# R plots into LaTex - tikz connection error

Tags: r, latex, tikz

I have been trying to do the importing R plots into LaTex using tikz using the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890215/getting-r-plots-into-latex) listed in this other SO question but when I run the command to `plot` it returns the error

```
Error in file(texLog, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(texLog, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\Francis\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6T9Lae/tikzStringWidthCalc.log': No such file or directory
```

I have visited the tikz website and have not found any solutions. I have been playing around with this for a few days now alternating between trying the three solutions listed on the original question and each presents its own challenges.