# How to change font of labels in R plot?

Tags: r, fonts, plot, ggplot2

Does anybody know how can I change the font (to "computer modern" style ) for the labels of my plot in R?

I have the below command to create the plot using ggplot in R:

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df$date, y = df$domain_count)) + geom_bar(fill = "dark blue", stat = "identity")+labs(x="Date", y="# of counts per month", title="names per month")
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890215/getting-r-plots-into-latex/35989420#35989420

Answer (score 2):

An excellent example is provided [here](https://github.com/wch/fontcm).

Summarizing, you need to install `extrafont` and use `font_install('fontcm')` to get the 'Computer Modern' fonts.  Then with respect to `ggplot` you can use the `theme` and `element_text` functions to modify fonts.

For example:

```
p <- qplot(seq(5), seq(5)) +
  xlab("Made with CM fonts") + ylab("Made with CM fonts") +
  ggtitle("Made with CM fonts")

# With the new fonts
p + theme(text         = element_text(size=16, family="CM Roman"),
          axis.title.x = element_text(face="italic", family="CM Sans"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", family= "CM Roman Greek"))
```

Where the title is 'Computer Modern' and the axis titles are CM Sans and CM Roman Greek with *italic* and **bold** typeface.