# How to use Greek symbols in ggplot2?

Tags: r, graphics, unicode, utf-8, ggplot2

My categories need to be named with Greek letters.  I am using `ggplot2`, and it works beautifully with the data.  Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to put those greek symbols on the x axis (at the tick marks) and also make them appear in the legend.  Is there any way to do it?

UPDATE:
I had a look at the [link](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Axis-Attributes), however, there is no good method described to accomplish what I want to do.

Comment: See the discussion of the `expression` function here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395105/getting-latex-into-r-plots

Comment: Is there any hint on obtaining the `viewports` from a ggplot2.  If that can be done, I believe that changing x-tic marks will be straight forward.

Comment: You can use `latex2exp` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/latex2exp.html

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Here is a [link](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Plotmath) to an excellent wiki that explains how to put greek symbols in ggplot2. In summary, here is what you do to obtain greek symbols

1. **Text Labels:** Use `parse = T` inside `geom_text` or `annotate`.
2. **Axis Labels:** Use `expression(alpha)` to get greek alpha.
3. **Facet Labels:** Use `labeller = label_parsed` inside `facet`.
4. **Legend Labels:** Use `bquote(alpha == .(value))` in legend label.

You can see detailed usage of these options in the link

EDIT. The objective of using greek symbols along the tick marks can be achieved as follows

```
require(ggplot2);
data(tips);
p0 = qplot(sex, data = tips, geom = 'bar');
p1 = p0 + scale_x_discrete(labels = c('Female' = expression(alpha),
                                      'Male'   = expression(beta)));
print(p1);
```

For complete documentation on the various symbols that are available when doing this and how to use them, see `?plotmath`.

Comment: I want those Greek Symbols to mark the tics.  I am not sure I follow this answer.  I will try this and write back.  Thank you for the direction.

Comment: This doesnt work for my purpose at least.  Thank you for the pointer though.

Comment: @Sam, check out the example code in my edit. It gives you greek symbols along your x-axis tick marks. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I would like to add an asterisk ('*') after a Greek letter. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I recently learned that another option is to use `substitute`, this also works in places where `expression` does not work, and even allows other formatting like `italics`, `bold` etc.

Comment: This is now out of date for legend labels. See `?scales::label_parse()`

Answer (score 102):

**Simplest solution: Use Unicode Characters**

No `expression` or other packages needed.
Not sure if this is a newer feature for ggplot, but it works.
It also makes it easy to mix Greek and regular text (like adding '*' to the ticks)

Just use unicode characters within the text string.
seems to work well for all options I can think of.
**Edit:** previously it did not work in facet labels. This has apparently been fixed at some point.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, 
       aes(mpg, disp, color=factor(gear))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title="Title (\u03b1 \u03a9)", # works fine
       x= "\u03b1 \u03a9 x-axis title",    # works fine
       y= "\u03b1 \u03a9 y-axis title",    # works fine
       color="\u03b1 \u03a9 Groups:") +  # works fine
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 35, 5), 
                     labels = paste0(seq(10, 35, 5), "\u03a9*")) + # works fine; to label the ticks
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = paste(rownames(mtcars), "\u03a9*")), size =3) + # works fine 
  facet_grid(~paste0(gear, " Gears \u03a9"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Nice answer. For more on unicode characters, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690729/greek-letters-symbols-and-line-breaks-inside-a-ggplot-legend-label

Comment: very flexible!!

Comment: This is the best way because you don't faff about with the object types formed by `expression` or `bquote` - you end up with a character object that you can use in any other way you use character objects.

Comment: This is not only the easiest Method, but also the best, since it works in most cases and doesn't rely on other functions.

Comment: This generates a lot of warnings, about a hundred lines of:
`Warning message in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :
“conversion failure on '>3σ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <cf>`

Comment: Sorry @Patafikss, I cannot reproduce any error messages. I would guess it may be a system issue. you may try it wit omitting the `ggrepel` line which introduces another package.

Comment: I solved the issue. I needed to use `device = cairo_pdf` in the ggsave(). Using Linux here, it's apparently a problem of the default device.

Answer (score 57):

Use `expression(delta)` where 'delta' for lowercase `δ` and 'Delta' to get capital `Δ`.

Here's full list of Greek characters:

> Α α   alpha
>   Β β   beta
>    Γ γ  gamma
>    Δ δ  delta
>    Ε ε  epsilon
>   Ζ ζ   zeta
>   Η η   eta
>   Θ θ   theta
>   Ι ι   iota
>   Κ κ   kappa
>   Λ λ   lambda
>   Μ μ   mu
>   Ν ν   nu
>   Ξ ξ   xi
>   Ο ο   omicron
>   Π π   pi
>   Ρ ρ   rho
>   Σ σ   sigma
>   Τ τ   tau
>   Υ υ   upsilon
>   Φ φ   phi
>   Χ χ   chi
>   Ψ ψ   psi
>   Ω ω   omega

**EDIT:** Copied from comments, when using in conjunction with other words use like: `expression(Delta*"price")`

Comment: How can I get a label like `Δprice`? `expression(Deltaprice)` doesn't work, neither does `expression(Delta price)`

Comment: thanks. But how's that exactly? `xlab(expression(Delta)price)` gives an error

Comment: expression(Delta*price)

Comment: Is there a way to get a Greek-form (as opposed to Latin-form) Upsilon?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsilon Correspondence with Latin Y (I'd like something like the third character in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsilon#/media/File:Y-like_European_letters.svg)

Comment: expression(Delta*"price") works. Don't love the syntax.

Answer (score 24):

You do not need the `latex2exp` package to do what you wanted to do. The following code would do the trick.

```
ggplot(smr, aes(Fuel.Rate, Eng.Speed.Ave., color=Eng.Speed.Max.)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title=expression("Fuel Efficiency"~(alpha*Omega)), 
color=expression(alpha*Omega), x=expression(Delta~price))
```

[image]

Also, some comments (unanswered as of this point) asked about putting an asterisk (*) after a Greek letter. `expression(alpha~"*")` works, so I suggest giving it a try.

More comments asked about getting `Δ Price` and I find the most straightforward way to achieve that is `expression(Delta~price))`. If you need to add something before the Greek letter, you can also do this:
`expression(Indicative~Delta~price)` which gets you:

[image]