# How to use subscripts in ggplot2 legends [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can I use subscripts in ggplot2 legends? I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2) on greek letters in legends and elsewhere, but I can't figure out how to adapt it.

I thought that using `expression()`, which works in axis labels, would do the trick. But my attempt below fails. Thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)
temp <- data.frame(a = rep(1:4, each = 100), b = rnorm(4 * 100), c = 1 + rnorm(4 * 100))
names(temp)[2:3] <- c("expression(b[1])", "expression(c[1])")
temp.m <- melt(temp, id.vars = "a")
ggplot(temp.m, aes(x = value, linetype = variable)) + geom_density() + facet_wrap(~ a)
```

Comment: `"expression(b[1])"` will be treated as character, not an expression.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The following should work (remove your line with `names(temp) <-`...):

```
ggplot(temp.m, aes(x = value, linetype = variable)) + 
  geom_density() + facet_wrap(~ a) +    
  scale_linetype_discrete(breaks=levels(temp.m$variable),
                          labels=c(expression(b[1]), expression(c[1])))
```

See `help(scale_linetype_discrete)` for available customization (e.g. legend title via `name=`).

Answer (score 13):

If you want to incorporate Greek symbols etc. into the major tick labels, use an unevaluated [expression](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/expression.html).

For a bar graph, i did the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(names=tolower(LETTERS[1:4]),mean_p=runif(4))

p <- ggplot(data,aes(x=names,y=mean_p))
p <- p + geom_bar(colour="black",fill="white")
p <- p + xlab("expressions") + scale_y_continuous(expression(paste("Wacky Data")))
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(labels=c(a=expression(paste(Delta^2)),
                               b=expression(paste(q^n)),
                               c=expression(log(z)),
                               d=expression(paste(omega / (x + 13)^2))))
p
```

[image: barplot with greek letters and superscripts]

Comment: `Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.`

Comment: Interestingly, this question is about subscripts, but your answer has only superscripts :( While `x^2` works for me, `x_2` does not.