# How to change ggplot2 x-axis values in barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a barplot in R, where the last bar in the graph indicates that last is the sum of all values whose the frequency is greater than a certain threshold. I want to represent this information on x-value correspondent to the last bar. For instance:

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(4000, 3000, 2000, 1000, 500)

df <- data.frame(x, y)

names(df) <- c("Var1", "Freq")

theme_set(theme_classic())

g <- ggplot(df, aes(Var1, Freq))
g + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5, fill = 'tomato2') + 
  xlab('Var1') +
  ylab('Freq') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, 
                                   vjust = 0.6, 
                                   colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"))
```

The above code produces a chart similar to this:

[image]

But on the last bar, I want that last value of x-axis (`x = 5`) be displayed as `>= 5`.

So far, I've tried to use `scale_x_discrete`. So I added to the above code the following lines:

```
n <- 5

# I'm not very creative with names.
.foo <- function(x, n) {
  if (x == n) {
    element <- paste('\u2265', toString(x), sep = ' ')
  } else {
    element <- toString(x)
  }
}

labels <- sapply(seq(n), .foo, n)

g + scale_x_discrete(breaks = sapply(seq(n), function(x) toString(x)),
                     labels = labels)
```

This code formats the x-axis as I wish but it overrides the barplot, leaving an empty chart:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646100/how-to-set-expressions-as-axis-text-of-facets-in-ggplot2/21650177#21650177

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the labels in `scale_x_continuous`:

```
... + scale_x_continuous(labels=c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "\u2265 5"))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: When I changed to `scale_x_continuous` I got the following error: `Erro: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

Comment: Using `scale_x_discrete(labels=c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "\u2265 5"))` did not worked either.

Comment: @marcelo The answer above with `scale_x_continuous` should work, unless your actual `df$Var1` isn't integer / numeric. And are you sure you've assigned the full ggplot object (i.e. `g + geom_bar(...)`) back to `g`? You haven't done that in the code included in the question, & getting a blank plot would be perfectly reasonable in that case.

Comment: @marcelo this assumes that the column `Var1` is numeric/integer, as above in the code in your question (I used `ggplot2` 3.1.0).

Comment: @Z.Lin I assigned the `geom_bar(...)`  to ggplot object first and then I used `scale_x_discrete`, changing the order of assigment fixed my problem, i.e., first assign `scale_x_discrete` and then `geom_bar(...)`. Sorry my bad. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to avoid changing the axis tick labels directly, but convert your categorical data in `Var1` to a factor, then relevel that factor  using `forcats::fct_lump` such that the final factor is `≥5`

```
# Insert after df generated, before plot call
library(forcats)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Var1 = as_factor(Var1),
         Var1 = fct_lump_min(Var1, min = 501, w = Freq, other_level = "≥5"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, as pointed out by @Z.Lin comment, I was assign the `geom_bar(...)` to the ggplot object before using `scale_x_discret`. Here is the solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
  ...
  labels <- sapply(seq(n), .foo, n)

  g <- ggplot(df, aes(Var1, Freq)) + 
         scale_x_discrete(breaks = sapply(seq(n), function(x) toString(x)),
                          labels = labels)

  g + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5, fill = color) + 
  ...
```