# Large space between y-ticks and y-label

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, tikz

In an Knitr document, I'm using a custom label function which outputs some LaTeX code (it's useless here, just to illustrate the problem). In normal plots, everything is fine: R manages to correctly guess the metrics of the output and leaves a reasonable space (middle plot). But when using facets, these metrics are simply using the plain string, not interpreting it as LaTeX (first plot), as we would expect from a non-LaTeX output device (last plot).

How can I convince ggplot to **always** interpret my label as LaTeX and use the smart metrics?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
<<dev='tikz', echo=F, fig.height=1.5>>=
library(ggplot2)

mylabel <- function() {
  function(xs) { sprintf("\\ensuremath{\\num{%g}}",xs) }
}
data <- data.frame(x=c(1,10), y=c(1,10), kind=c("a","a"))

ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=mylabel()) +
  facet_grid(~ kind)
@

<<dev='tikz', echo=F, fig.height=1.5>>=
ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=mylabel())
@

<<echo=F, fig.height=1.5>>=
ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=mylabel())
@
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this helps...

but have you seen this post? 
[How to use subscripts in ggplot2 legends [R]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202667/how-to-use-subscripts-in-ggplot2-legends-r)

have you tried using:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels=c(expression(paste(_________)), expression(paste(_________))))
```

where `______` is the expression you want?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use that because I'd like to use custom TeX code (like `\num` in the question which handles showing `1.2e5` in a proper format for example, would be annoying to have to replicate that in R)

Comment: I really don't understando much about what you want... bu have you seen this? https://github.com/crowding/analysis/blob/master/occlusion.R