# R - Interpreting a subscript in a variable used in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, subscript

I'm using ggplot to do some multiline plots that are constructed with lots of variables and the use of paste. I have not been able to figure out how to get the subscript 3 in O3 to appear in the following simplified version of the code.

```
gasSubscript <- "O[3]"
color1 <- paste(gasSubscript,"some additional text")
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), y = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
testPlot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x)) + geom_line(aes(y = y, color = color1))
```

color1 contains

```
  "O[3] some additional text"
```

The legend displays as "O[3] some additional text" rather than with a subscripted 3.

Comment: If [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6202667/324364) question doesn't answer your question, can you explain in detail why?

Comment: In the question/answer you linked to, the relevant line of code is "labels=c(expression(b[1]), expression(c[1])". I would like to replace "expression(b[1]" with a variable that includes O[3] and have this interpreted as O subscript 3. I can't figure out how to make this happen.

Comment: You'll have to convert the text to an expression yourself at some point. There's no other way that I know of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you need the label in the scale to be an expression so that, when it is rendered, it is rendered according to the rules of `plotmath`. However, `ggplot` works with `data.frame`s and `data.frame`s can not have a column which is a vector of expressions. So the way around this is to store the information as the text (string) version of the `plotmath` expression and, as the last step for making the labels, turn these into expressions. This can be done because the `labels` argument to the scale functions can itself be a function which can transform/format the labels.

Putting this together with your example:

```
color1 <- paste(gasSubscript,"*\" some additional text\"")
```

This is now in a format that can be made into an expression.

```
> color1
[1] "O[3] *\" some additional text\""
> cat(color1)
O[3] *" some additional text"
> parse(text=color1)
expression(O[3] *" some additional text")
```

With that format, you can force the scale to interpret the labels as expressions which will cause them to be rendered as per the rules of `plotmath`.

```
testPlot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = y, color = color1)) +
  scale_colour_discrete(labels = function(x) parse(text=x))
```

[image]

Using the `labels` function approach works for data which is stored in the `data.frame` as well, so long as the strings are formatted so that they can be parsed.

```
DF <- data.frame(x=1:4, y=rep(1:2, times=2), 
                 group = rep(c('O[3]*" some additional text"', 
                               'H[2]*" some different text"'), each = 2))

ggplot(DF, aes(x, y, colour=group)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_discrete(labels=function(x) parse(text=x))
```

[image]

Comment: This works. Thanks! But I really don't understand the logic. I suspect it is lack of understanding about the complexities of ggplot2. Given these complexities and the fact that I will probably want to use it a lot, can you recommend a source or two (book, link) that provide some more in depth explanation. Amazon has a bunch of books that purport to do this so my problem is choice anxiety!

Comment: @GeraldNelson I can not personally recommend any particular book. I didn't learn from a book because there weren't any at the time.

Comment: This works, but aligns all labels to the right, which looks weird if you have multiple labels.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what I think you want. It took me a little tinkering to get the right order of paste and expression.

```
require(ggplot2)
test <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), y = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
colour1 <- "1"

testPlot <- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x)) + geom_line(aes(y = y, colour = colour1))
testPlot + scale_colour_discrete(labels = c(expression(paste(O[3], "some other text here"))))
```

[image: Subscript legend label]

It also returns the warning

```
Warning message:
In is.na(scale$labels) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression'
```

to which I haven't been able to find an explanation.

Comment: This answer doesn't do it for me. I need to have the variable gasSubscript interpreted, rather that putting the code that defined gasSubscript (paste(O[3], "some other text here")) into the expression code.