# Symbols in ggplot2 breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data with the word `alpha` in it, and I'd like to use ggplot2 to render the `alpha` in the breaks as the symbol.

```
df <- data.frame(Method = c("Method (alpha = 0.01)", "Method (alpha = 0.05)"),
                 Value = c(2,3))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Method,
               y = Value)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

I couldn't find this on the site, but I don't think it will be that difficult a question. I can get single values in breaks to work using the `expression` command in `ggplot2::xlab`, etc., but I can't figure out how to create a vector of expressions. For example, the code

```
c(expression("Method (alpha = 0.01)"),
+ expression("Method (alpha = 0.05)"))
```

gives as output

```
expression("Method (alpha = 0.01)", "Method (alpha = 0.05)")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use subscripts in ggplot2 legends \[R\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202667/how-to-use-subscripts-in-ggplot2-legends-r)

Comment: True. My apologies. I do prefer parsing, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parse` as in the following possibilities.  I think this is easier than having to write out lists of expressions.

#### Edit

To increase the space between 'Method' and the rest,

```
df$Method <- gsub("Method", "Method~", as.character(df$Method))
```

Then, plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Method, y = Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = parse(text=gsub('=','==',as.character(df$Method))))
```

or

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Method, y = Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = parse(text=paste("alpha", c(0.01, 0.05), sep="==")))
```

The result from the first one,
[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Apologies for following up a question in a comment, but how do you get a space between "Method" and "(\alpha = 0.01)"?

Comment: No problem, see the dreaded `?plotmath` page for more terrible ways to format expression in R.  For the space, do the following prior to the plotting code above.  `df$Method <- gsub("Method", "Method~", as.character(df$Method))`.  Add more "~" if you want more spaces.