# R: Programmatically changing ggplot scale labels to Greek letters with expressions

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, expression, figure

I am trying to change the labels in a `ggplot` object to Greek symbols for an **arbitrary** number of labels. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2), I can do this manually when I know the number of labels in advance and the number is not too large:

```
    # Simulate data 
   df <- data.frame(name = rep(c("alpha1","alpha2"), 50),
               value = rnorm(100))
   
   # Create a plot with greek letters for labels
   ggplot(df, aes(x = value, y = name)) + geom_density() +
     scale_y_discrete(labels = c("alpha1" = expression(alpha[1]),
                                 "alpha2" = expression(alpha[2])))
```

For our purposes, assume I need to change `k` default labels, where each of the `k` labels is the pre-fix "alpha" followed by a number `1:k`. Their corresponding updated labels would substitute the greek letter for "alpha" and use a subscript. An example of this is below:

```
# default labels
paste0("alpha", 1:k)

# desired labels
for (i in 1:k) { expression(alpha[i]) }
```

I was able to hack together the below programmatic solution that appears to produce the desired result thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69406548/adding-greek-letters-in-legend-of-ggplot):

```
   ggplot(df, aes(x = value, y = name)) + geom_density() +
       scale_y_discrete(labels = parse(text = paste("alpha[", 1:length(unique(df)), "]")))
```

However, I do not understand this code and am seeking clarification about:

1. What is `parse()` doing here that `expression()` otherwise would do?
2. While I understand everything to the right-hand side of `=`, what is `text` doing on the left-hand side of the `=`?

Comment: Check the documentation on [parse](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/parse) out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option to achieve your desired result would be to add a new column to your data which contains the `?plotmath` expression as a string and map this new column on `y`. Afterwards you could use `scales::label_parse()` to parse the expressions:

```r
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(name = rep(c("alpha1","alpha2"), 50),
                 value = rnorm(100))
df$label <- gsub("^(.*?)(\\d+)$", "\\1[\\2]", df$name)

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(df, aes(x = value, y = label)) + geom_density() +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = scales::label_parse())
```

[image]

Comment: While this is helpful, it does not directly address the questions. If you add an answer to (1) and (2) then I can accept. I'm still not sure about the difference between parse(text=foo) vs. expression(foo)  here - is it just that parse returns a list of unevaluated expressions? I missed the "text" argument in parse() documentation previously so (2) is clear.