# How to fix the legend for a grouped scatter plot added with geom_ablines

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, scatter-plot, scale-color-manual

I want to make a scatter plot with two different groups (based on Size) each plotted with specified colors (Blue and Red). In addition, I want to add 4 geom_ablines to the scatter plot with the same Blue and Red colors (2 lines **one solid and one dashed** with the Blue color and 2 lines **one solid and one dashed** with the Red color.

Then I want to show a legend where those 4 lines are visible. i.e. Dashed Blue, Dashed Red, Solid Blue, and Solid Red.

I have been using the scale_color manual but it is not helping me solve my issue.

The code I have is as follows:

```
    cols <- c("Blue", "Red")
    ###Plotting data
    fig <- ggplot(scalingdata, aes(x=Re, y=Sw, color=Size)) + 
      geom_point(size=3) +
      scale_color_manual(values=cols) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f0f4f5",
                                            size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_rect(color = "black",fill = NA,size = 1),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "italic"),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size=17.5),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
            axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_blank())
            # legend.position ="none")                                    # If no legend to be shown
    
    # Converting scale with better numbering style format
    fig <- fig + scale_x_log10(limits = c(1,10^8), breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                               labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) + 
      scale_y_log10(limits = c(1,10^8), breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                    labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) + annotation_logticks()
    
    
    # ###Scaling fit by Vladimir Nikora___Dashed for Fishes and Solid line for Larva
    fig <- fig + geom_abline(aes(intercept=1, slope = 13/15, color="Sw ~ Re^13/15"), size=1, linetype="solid") #Undulating High Re
        
    fig <- fig + geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0.79, slope = 9/10, color="Sw ~ Re^9/10"), size=1.25, linetype="dashed") #Motionless High Re
            
    fig <- fig + geom_abline(aes(intercept = 1.35, slope = 2/3, color="Sw ~ Re^2/3"), size=1, linetype="solid") #Undulating Low Re

    fig <- fig + geom_abline(aes(intercept = 1.1, slope = 3/4, color="Sw ~ Re^3/4"), size=1.25, linetype="dashed") #Motionless Low Re

    fig <- fig + scale_color_manual(values=c("Sw ~ Re^13/15"= "Blue" ,"Sw ~ Re^9/10"="Blue",
                                     "Sw ~ Re^2/3" = "Red", "Sw ~ Re^3/4" = "Red"))
```

The output plot I am getting is:
[image]

**The issue is that the scatter points are colorless instead of being BLUE and RED respectively based on Size. Moreover, in the legend, the dashed lines are not dashed but all of them are solid.**

If someone can help me with this, it would be a great help. Thank you

THE MRE using dput is:

```
    structure(list(Sw = c(118612, 119946, 122211, 122442, 124753, 
126631, 128301, 128781, 135193, 137232, 137489, 137744, 138263, 
141664, 144336, 150394, 152376, 152664, 156417, 158480, 160867, 
162985, 170000, 172000, 172000, 175000, 183000, 185000, 185000, 
193000, 198000, 202000, 206000, 209000, 213000, 213000, 214000, 
221000, 221000, 221000, 221000, 232000, 236000, 236000, 240000, 
240000, 241000, 248000, 251000, 256000, 258000, 260000, 271000, 
272000, 274000, 292000, 297000, 299000, 308000, 315000, 327000, 
327000, 329000, 342000, 359000, 366000, 368000, 376000, 377000, 
387000, 394000, 396000, 407000, 416000, 420000, 428000, 431000, 
456000, 456000, 463000, 473000, 490000, 491000, 498000, 512000, 
518000, 524000, 528000, 574000, 592000, 609000, 611000, 631000, 
634000, 646000, 669000, 672000, 677000, 703000, 751000, 762000, 
781000, 794000, 823000, 846000, 849000, 853000, 882000, 887000, 
898000, 941000, 979000, 1030000, 1060000, 1070000, 1080000, 1090000, 
1140000, 1170000, 6469900, 7584900, 7914000, 7995300, 8139300, 
8254100, 8482100, 8485600, 8557900, 8642000, 8730800, 8734400, 
8779000, 8812900, 8869100, 8902600, 8914600, 8975200, 9075000, 
9203000, 9269900, 9481200, 9565700, 9656200, 9664300, 9821400, 
9825700, 9989900, 10410400, 10552900, 10820800, 10959400, 11449900, 
11855900, 41766.8, 44815, 46421, 51017, 52530, 54453, 55151, 
60703, 60748, 61022, 61850, 62083, 64308, 65524, 66017, 66115, 
66963, 69001, 70887, 74872, 74928, 76174, 85619, 85940, 300720, 
349790, 414460, 507870, 538620, 540430, 570270, 595730, 617120, 
667810, 687150, 697620, 704690, 717830, 741100, 754920, 760010, 
769000, 825210, 875180, 899020, 1042220, 1665250, 1687780, 1930520, 
2071620, 1484730, 1560040, 2205640, 3198090, 3225130, 4840500, 
73.698, 91.148, 91.843, 126.687, 130.467, 155.199, 232.717, 602.22, 
615.05, 619.05, 626.62, 655.73, 677.34, 747.73, 768.65, 778.66, 
816.82, 859.61, 885.06, 906.12, 925.43, 975.49, 1020.79, 1024.12, 
1091.84, 1094.5, 1114.2, 1122.36, 1165.94, 1290.31, 1291.33, 
1302.88, 1361.19, 1477.34, 1543.46, 1564.86, 1609.89, 1679.22, 
1720.21, 1748.66, 1769.04, 1778.18, 1804.09, 1816.32, 1842.21, 
1861.27, 1861.88, 1875.09, 1957.71, 1975.41, 2028.23, 2049.21, 
2193.15, 2214.41, 2320.91, 190.301, 213.437, 215.963, 217.451, 
226.594, 227.932, 243.172, 244.607, 292.403, 297.318, 308.91, 
310.428, 319.697, 332.16, 339.738, 345.449, 363.165, 388.971, 
399.016, 414.572, 415.794, 453.714), Re = c(77600, 36434, 49900, 
70000, 81300, 54900, 83300, 73400, 49100, 70000, 78800, 53200, 
86600, 79400, 71700, 50700, 58000, 97400, 64200, 92200, 79400, 
70000, 69500, 95900, 54800, 74500, 128000, 61200, 94400, 121000, 
108000, 139000, 102000, 156000, 46100, 125000, 83200, 113000, 
123000, 94400, 146000, 88600, 82600, 155000, 102000, 155000, 
125000, 169000, 122000, 81900, 114000, 159000, 133000, 155000, 
114000, 169000, 144000, 209000, 156000, 189000, 137000, 168000, 
186000, 187000, 184000, 186000, 246000, 152000, 231000, 332000, 
202000, 222000, 239000, 214000, 302000, 219000, 307000, 260000, 
312000, 241000, 348000, 235000, 196000, 324000, 244000, 324000, 
357000, 250000, 357000, 380000, 337000, 3e+05, 351000, 414000, 
389000, 293000, 417000, 335000, 374000, 512000, 401000, 343000, 
537000, 414000, 595000, 392000, 448000, 421000, 633000, 496000, 
633000, 466000, 648000, 524000, 729000, 516000, 504000, 795000, 
802000, 4114000, 3809200, 4687400, 4130800, 4228400, 4891300, 
3757100, 3974800, 4798000, 4516600, 4074300, 4310400, 4479500, 
3904400, 4358000, 6464600, 3851100, 4824400, 4412200, 5069000, 
4642300, 4316300, 6473400, 4096700, 4572600, 5340600, 5041200, 
5224500, 5429300, 5481800, 5952800, 7097300, 7165900, 7781600, 
25778, 29630, 20784, 28523, 38410, 36744, 33414, 56160, 41702, 
49165, 30384, 42771, 33623, 46439, 47329, 24810, 38161, 56150, 
51390, 47929, 54400, 56860, 59810, 67890, 303110, 236540, 282380, 
354240, 408170, 391180, 377560, 408170, 391180, 402420, 526760, 
435040, 411070, 585800, 508420, 450730, 497730, 463680, 477010, 
745400, 553540, 846800, 889800, 935100, 1047300, 1148400, 553800, 
723800, 746600, 1720200, 2939400, 2374500, 10.115, 10.11, 12.227, 
29.025, 20.106, 10.165, 17.613, 83.12, 105.2, 123.1, 148.64, 
113.79, 111.14, 333.77, 120.21, 283, 206.68, 287.45, 341.67, 
318.34, 291.98, 366.66, 456.8, 296.57, 467.7, 439.2, 415.7, 390.39, 
456.8, 308.38, 478.8, 671.2, 606, 587.2, 542.8, 749, 760.9, 692.4, 
659.3, 667.6, 643, 560.6, 777.7, 686.5, 735.2, 856.6, 690.8, 
870, 710.4, 894.7, 730.6, 825, 817.3, 920.1, 880.8, 25.031, 32.901, 
29.787, 27.193, 23.62, 29.056, 30.791, 23.425, 30.537, 36.339, 
50.199, 58.272, 52.758, 54.085, 68.21, 27.193, 71.09, 50.617, 
48.967, 44.702, 73.49, 73.49), Species = c("Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", 
"Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", 
"Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", 
"Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", 
"Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", 
"Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Sharks", "Sharks", "Sharks", "Sharks", "Sharks", "Sharks", "Ascidian Larvae", 
"Ascidian Larvae", "Ascidian Larvae", "Ascidian Larvae", "Ascidian Larvae", 
"Ascidian Larvae", "Ascidian Larvae", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61"), Size = c("Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae"
), St = c(0.243268582034501, 0.523959877133545, 0.389788362056428, 
0.278388628178544, 0.244219067477153, 0.367102048635318, 0.245134340978561, 
0.279238212500755, 0.438219631492664, 0.31201571537706, 0.277690390877163, 
0.412078707080919, 0.254101483129468, 0.283960618825043, 0.320386808203692, 
0.472108334099284, 0.418126498248202, 0.249457632595693, 0.387764494072905, 
0.273566338387061, 0.322452372293089, 0.370568682018262, 0.38929895045003, 
0.285449282566378, 0.499536244491161, 0.373853018937899, 0.227541300611154, 
0.481104503595853, 0.311902495975278, 0.253858117251408, 0.291783380018674, 
0.231289376443841, 0.321429819699716, 0.213226316167493, 0.73535626042963, 
0.271199388846448, 0.409363920393332, 0.311266904187258, 0.28596065181431, 
0.372597035732629, 0.240912055980549, 0.416747860646413, 0.454727345483648, 
0.242325669270641, 0.374481343339475, 0.246432884004042, 0.306850012732366, 
0.233552269751365, 0.327440961481463, 0.497479489076128, 0.360191923659416, 
0.260252757478063, 0.324292396384391, 0.279290601871247, 0.382529407297209, 
0.274988962771768, 0.328256302521008, 0.227690032080688, 0.314228255404726, 
0.265257618198795, 0.37987988825258, 0.309783004110735, 0.281515343185172, 
0.291074135050228, 0.310524407391415, 0.313175123421803, 0.23808488657843, 
0.393698149116106, 0.259745771586872, 0.185520538993253, 0.310430202684134, 
0.283897342720872, 0.271028913657513, 0.309384586459903, 0.221340793993696, 
0.311041809833107, 0.223438501844327, 0.279132632073809, 0.232610526728174, 
0.305761686039938, 0.216322161048327, 0.331854211704024, 0.398698440415127, 
0.244626470116666, 0.333963689797827, 0.254450826346251, 0.233605028464149, 
0.336134453781513, 0.255895584615308, 0.247946068379505, 0.287611672670147, 
0.324144809438927, 0.286115482193914, 0.243729463678313, 0.264302963531755, 
0.363393883771318, 0.256479308531784, 0.321634759738359, 0.299159527690512, 
0.233447427266361, 0.302433374165808, 0.362389853900744, 0.235323518267981, 
0.316386985184939, 0.226293726046568, 0.344699568138944, 0.303033145076212, 
0.333430716272689, 0.223017542504579, 0.288146783640142, 0.236594709692005, 
0.334361212296077, 0.252977172911813, 0.321953903004644, 0.233601359236799, 
0.333114218203138, 0.344203337900817, 0.228221648865378, 0.232183102213908, 
0.250295128437197, 0.316909457357351, 0.268709577645423, 0.308048935041855, 
0.306358622430061, 0.268574355248053, 0.359310368633893, 0.339771064454215, 
0.283874302307228, 0.3045241557553, 0.341051647591493, 0.322503638696486, 
0.311913824779625, 0.359239145081061, 0.323900368274474, 0.219176667244061, 
0.368414047393468, 0.296087410852063, 0.327348653980426, 0.288952360656955, 
0.317805173505505, 0.349599499061661, 0.23518164782688, 0.375138127690756, 
0.336377010833042, 0.292686346632698, 0.310204924915008, 0.304323523404437, 
0.30517060120053, 0.306385178491378, 0.289305836077696, 0.245760867447159, 
0.254302170218483, 0.242484923070044, 0.257870165748749, 0.240719274240546, 
0.355471244064845, 0.2846681185215, 0.217661796677678, 0.235860109140741, 
0.262690301692974, 0.17202920082822, 0.231843122013434, 0.197537480456343, 
0.323976771042564, 0.231016184479705, 0.304402110063851, 0.224562202134299, 
0.221997238656593, 0.424123516982184, 0.279276421804133, 0.195580134425664, 
0.219536681625896, 0.248622358777944, 0.219212016357345, 0.213215622321579, 
0.227832389358595, 0.20146919759615, 0.157899648862937, 0.235354178413181, 
0.233597292524979, 0.228178161508506, 0.210019930393074, 0.219878073423756, 
0.240388487016993, 0.232288390949214, 0.251079985698921, 0.264114641433334, 
0.207614593756514, 0.255216558855981, 0.272835854188107, 0.19502547907645, 
0.231992157091137, 0.266565280053204, 0.243021448263837, 0.263953297612413, 
0.27533163553866, 0.186864632918074, 0.258487448689974, 0.195883416277148, 
0.297855865613987, 0.287261150364813, 0.293374469828208, 0.28710187409247, 
0.426691163020906, 0.343033292092993, 0.47018174096222, 0.295890385833758, 
0.17462549544427, 0.32444207224037, 1.15960193451398, 1.43487842039073, 
1.1954881211204, 0.694670633111126, 1.03274740893889, 2.42996854423028, 
2.10287709536259, 1.15310473651356, 0.930494475702483, 0.800362608672448, 
0.670946160047344, 0.917149369794335, 0.969963623056172, 0.356546865546547, 
1.01767041791117, 0.437905647321569, 0.628994758168588, 0.475946636660009, 
0.41227308378791, 0.453016082808868, 0.504440080025434, 0.423426859723028, 
0.355655416919196, 0.549594966348079, 0.371544423161221, 0.396618119014455, 
0.426581724604903, 0.457564804982094, 0.406227408970275, 0.66592753876014, 
0.429242005148684, 0.308938181405404, 0.357491106253483, 0.400417939035907, 
0.452558426733727, 0.332516184043711, 0.336734593477769, 0.385984313372426, 
0.415257522282799, 0.416877219867739, 0.437870609858534, 0.504826034458151, 
0.3692029958207, 0.421086132923672, 0.398797799365072, 0.345820252410603, 
0.428961656779362, 0.343022005040261, 0.43859585449659, 0.351397709779422, 
0.441831474644956, 0.395322591846656, 0.42707677378149, 0.383038227789757, 
0.419372655758695, 1.20999057171145, 1.0324754309382, 1.15390937655487, 
1.27269225907284, 1.52681925668428, 1.24850012592141, 1.25692362442215, 
1.66191343132771, 1.52396351968135, 1.30216898419267, 0.979390794690607, 
0.84785205830123, 0.964426984707154, 0.977438888352537, 0.792711561574157, 
2.02183603756457, 0.813045009817121, 1.22303796362965, 1.29689832478866, 
1.47601961377895, 0.900469664727307, 0.982591604164768)), row.names = 300:585, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: For your line issue, it's because your linetype is set manually, rather than with an aesthetic, so there is no scale to include in the legend

Comment: But if I bring the linetype inside the aes(), it creates a new legend with dashed and solid lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

Your first problem with the point colors is simple: in ggplot2 you can only have a single scale for each aesthetic – if you add another one, it will replace the first. You set the colors for the points in the first block, but then replace that scale at the end, leaving the points without color.

The simple way to get around that would be to combine the 2 scales into a single `scale_color_manual` which includes colors for the lines and points:

```
scale_color_manual(values=c("Sw ~ Re^13/15"= "Blue" ,"Sw ~ Re^9/10"="Blue",
                            "Sw ~ Re^2/3" = "Red", "Sw ~ Re^3/4" = "Red",
                            'Fish' = 'Blue', 'Larvae'='Red'))
```

Your bigger problem is combining the legend for the lines and hiding the legend for the points. To do that, you need to get rid of the separate lines, with manually defined linetypes, and move the linetype into the `aes`.

The easiest way is to make a data.frame with all the line information (called `lines` in the code below), then use scales to set the color, size, and linetype for each kind of line (the `name` variable in names). By naming the scales the same (with the `name` argument), it will combine them if possible.

To eliminate the point colors from the legend, use the `breaks` argument in `scale_color_manual` and provide the names of the lines only. It will still color all the values listed in `values`, but only the ones included in `breaks` will appear on the plot

```
fig <- ggplot(scalingdata, aes(x=Re, y=Sw, color=Size)) + 
    geom_point(size=3, show.legend = FALSE) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f0f4f5",
                                          size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_rect(color = "black",fill = NA,size = 1),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "italic"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size=17.5),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank())+
    scale_x_log10(limits = c(1,10^8), breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) + 
    scale_y_log10(limits = c(1,10^8), breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) + annotation_logticks()

lines <- data.frame(name = c("Sw ~ Re^13/15", "Sw ~ Re^9/10", "Sw ~ Re^2/3", "Sw ~ Re^3/4"),
                    intercept = c(1, 0.79, 1.35, 1.1),
                    slope = c(13/15, 9/10, 2/3, 3/4))

fig + geom_abline(data = lines, aes(intercept=intercept, slope=slope, color=name, size=name, linetype=name))+
    scale_color_manual(name='Size',
                       values=c("Sw ~ Re^13/15" ='Blue', "Sw ~ Re^9/10" ='Blue',
                                "Sw ~ Re^2/3" ='Red', "Sw ~ Re^3/4" ='Red',
                                'Fish' = 'Blue', 'Larvae' = 'Red'),
                       breaks=lines$name) +
    scale_size_manual(name='Size',
                      values=c("Sw ~ Re^13/15" =1, "Sw ~ Re^9/10" =1.25, "Sw ~ Re^2/3" =1, "Sw ~ Re^3/4" = 1.25)) +
    scale_linetype_manual(name='Size',
                          values=c("Sw ~ Re^13/15" ='solid', "Sw ~ Re^9/10" ='dashed',
                                   "Sw ~ Re^2/3" ='solid', "Sw ~ Re^3/4" ='dashed'))
```

[image]

Some further reading:

[Remove legend entries for some factors levels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21801950/8366499)

[How to merge color, line style and shape legends in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37140266/8366499)

Comment: Thanks, @divibisan for fixing the problem. Do you know how could I put the legend text in equation format (adding subscripts and superscripts)?

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaAshraf Take a look at this question [How to use subscripts in ggplot2 legends](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6202667/8366499)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I managed to fix this issue. However, two more things, if you could help with. 

How can I remove the dot on the lines in the legend? I want to show only lines.
Is there a way to make the lines in legend horizontally instead of tilted?

Thank you very much

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaAshraf You can hide the points in the legend by adding `show.legend = FALSE` to `geom_point`. Changing the appearance of the legend would be worth asking as a separate question

Answer (score 1):

For you colour prob, try this :

```
fig <- ggplot(scalingdata, aes(x=Re, y=Sw, colour=Size)) + 
  geom_point( size=3) +
  scale_color_manual(values=cols) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f0f4f5",
                                        size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black",fill = NA,size = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "italic"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=17.5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank())
# legend.position ="none")                                    # If no legend to be shown

# Converting scale with better numbering style format
fig <- fig + scale_x_log10(limits = c(1,10^8), breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                           labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) + 
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(1,10^8), breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) + annotation_logticks()

cols2 <- c("Blue", "Red", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Blue")

# ###Scaling fit by Vladimir Nikora___Dashed for Fishes and Solid line for Larva
fig <- fig + geom_abline(aes(intercept=1, slope = 13/15, color="Sw ~ Re^13/15"), size=1, linetype="solid") #Undulating High Re

fig <- fig + geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0.79, slope = 9/10, color="Sw ~ Re^9/10"), size=1.25, linetype="dashed") #Motionless High Re

fig <- fig + geom_abline(aes(intercept = 1.35, slope = 2/3, color="Sw ~ Re^2/3"), size=1, linetype="solid") #Undulating Low Re

fig <- fig + geom_abline(aes(intercept = 1.1, slope = 3/4, color="Sw ~ Re^3/4"), size=1.25, linetype="dashed") #Motionless Low Re

fig <- fig + scale_color_manual(values=cols2)

fig
```

Comment: It does work. But it is also adding scatter point groups in the legend which I do not want to show. I only want the legend for the 4 geom_ablines. How can I fix this?