# adding subscripts to a character vector that will be used as a ggplot label

Tags: r, subscript

I see a lot of examples for getting subscripts and superscripts into plot labels, but I'm curious how to add a subscript to a character vector that can eventually be used for a plot.

Example data and plot:

```
 data.frame(site = LETTERS[1:10],
            a1 = c(rep(1, 7), rep(NA, 3)),
            a2 = c(rep(NA, 4), rep(2, 6)),
            minY = sample(1:9, 10, replace = TRUE),
            maxY = sample(10:19, 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
 mutate(label = case_when(is.na(a1) ~ paste(site, a2, sep = ""), 
                          is.na(a2) ~ paste(site, a1, sep = ""), 
                          TRUE ~ paste(site, paste(a1, a2, sep = ","), sep = ""))) %>% 
 ggplot() +
 geom_segment(aes(x = label, xend = label, y = minY, yend = maxY))
```

[image]

How can I made the 1's and 2's into subscripts for the plot?

Comment: Plain text doesn't really support subscripts. Do you want to use some other markup style? Is this plotting or some other output?

Comment: @MrFlick I do plan on using the label in a plot, but because there was a few steps to generate the label, I was trying to set it up as a character in advance.

Comment: The "how to add subscripts" depends on the rendering mechanism and target format, e.g., R plots (base or grid/ggplot2), or rmarkdown into pdf, html, or docx. What's your intent?

Comment: @r2evans I've added a bit more detail about the downstream use of the subscripts in a ggplot and provided an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We convert the label to latex and use TeX on that.  `DF` is the data frame defined in the question, also shown in the Note at the end.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)

DF %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = label, xend = label, y = minY, yend = maxY)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ TeX(sub("(.)([0-9,]+)", "$\\1_{\\2}$", .x)))
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

This is as in the question except we have separated it out and named it `DF`.

```
DF <- data.frame(site = LETTERS[1:10],
            a1 = c(rep(1, 7), rep(NA, 3)),
            a2 = c(rep(NA, 4), rep(2, 6)),
            minY = sample(1:9, 10, replace = TRUE),
            maxY = sample(10:19, 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
 mutate(label = case_when(is.na(a1) ~ paste(site, a2, sep = ""), 
                          is.na(a2) ~ paste(site, a1, sep = ""), 
                          TRUE ~ paste(site, paste(a1, a2, sep = ","), sep = "")))
```

Comment: works perfectly!  Can you explain the syntax in the scale_x_discrete line?

Comment: `labels=` takes a function which can be provided in a short form as an formula where the part to the right of the tilde is the body and `.x` is the argument.  Each label is passed to that function which transforms it to a latex string using `sub`, e.g. `$F_{1,2}$`, and then `TeX` converts that to plotmath form which is passed back to ggplot for final use as the label.  The regular expression in the `sub` assumes labels consist of a single character followed by a subscript which may contain digits and commas.

Answer (score 3):

Form the expression/bquote string programmatically (e.g., `A[2]`) and then use `scales::label_parse()`.

Note that with R's [`plotmath`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) (which is how this is being done internally), we need to be explicit about the comma-separated subscripts. While a single number has an "expression" (symbolic) of `A[1]`, we can't use `A[1,2]` since the `,2` will be dropped from view; instead, we need `A[1*','*2]` which is the number 1 followed (multiplied, in math syntax) by the string-literal comma followed by the number 2.

```r
data.frame(site = LETTERS[1:10],
            a1 = c(rep(1, 7), rep(NA, 3)),
            a2 = c(rep(NA, 4), rep(2, 6)),
            minY = sample(1:9, 10, replace = TRUE),
            maxY = sample(10:19, 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(
     label = sprintf("%s[%s]", site,             # CHANGED
       mapply(function(x, y) paste(na.omit(c(x, y)), collapse = "*','*"), a1, a2))
  ) %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_segment(aes(x = label, xend = label, y = minY, yend = maxY)) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::label_parse()) # NEW
```

[image: ggplot grob with subscripted labels]

Note: this is nearly a duplicate of several questions such as [How to use subscripts in ggplot2 legends [R]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6202667/3358272), though I couldn't find quite the right verbiage to address *this* question.

Comment: works perfectly in the example, but not with my actual dataset.  syntax seems to be the same, so I can't figure out what's going on.