# Changing facet label to math formula in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder how to change the `facet` label to math formula in `ggplot2`.

```
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) +
  xlim(0, 2) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) + opts(aspect.ratio = 1)
d + facet_wrap(~ color, ncol = 4)
```

[image]

For example, I want to change facet label from `D` to `Y[1]`, where 1 is subscript. Thanks in advance for your help.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6539953/707145) but it does not work for me. I'm using `R 2.15.1` and `ggplot2 0.9.1`.

Comment: See this: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/docs/label_parsed.html  You have to rename you labels and then use the `label = parsed` argument.

Comment: @TylerRinker in won't work because `facet_wrap` doesn't has a  `labeller` param. Only `facet_grid` does, and I don't know why.

Comment: Hopefully the facet_wrap() wasn't a hard requirement.

Comment: See also https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/25

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps somebody has changed the name of the edit-Grob function at some point. [(Edit: It was removed by @hadley about 8 months ago.)](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/commit/1bc4d1e179536e3404418a9589d982c242a40793)  There is no `geditGrob` but just `editGrob` from pkg:grid seems to work:

```
 d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) +
              xlim(0, 2) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) + opts(aspect.ratio = 1)

 #Note: changes in ggplot2 functions cause this to fail from the very beginning now.
 # Frank Harrell's answer this year suggests `facet_warp` now accepts `labeller`


 d <- d + facet_wrap(~ color, ncol = 4)
 grob <- ggplotGrob(d)
 strip_elem <- grid.ls(getGrob(grob, "strip.text.x", grep=TRUE, global=TRUE))$name
#strip.text.x.text.1535
#strip.text.x.text.1541
#strip.text.x.text.1547
#strip.text.x.text.1553
#strip.text.x.text.1559
#strip.text.x.text.1565
#strip.text.x.text.1571
grob <- editGrob(grob, strip_elem[1], label=expression(Y[1]))
grid.draw(grob)
```

Comment: as of ggplot 0.9.2 this answer no longer works (at least for me).  `strip_elem <- grid.ls(getGrob(grob, "strip.text.x", grep=TRUE, global=TRUE))$name` gives
`Error in getGrob(grob, "strip.text.x", grep = TRUE, global = TRUE) : 
  It is only valid to get a child from a 'gTree'` any idea on how to make it work?

Answer (score 24):

You can edit the grobs in the gtable,

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) +
  xlim(0, 2) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) + facet_wrap(~ color, ncol = 4)


for(ii in 1:7)
grid.gedit(gPath(paste0("strip_t-", ii), "strip.text"), 
           grep=TRUE, label=bquote(gamma[.(ii)]))
```

[image]

alternatively, if you want to save a grob,

```
g <- ggplotGrob(d)
gg <- g$grobs

strips <- grep("strip_t", names(gg))
for(ii in strips)
  gg[[ii]] <- editGrob(getGrob(gg[[ii]], "strip.text", 
                               grep=TRUE, global=TRUE), 
                       label=bquote(gamma[.(ii)]))

g$grobs <- gg
```

using ggsave would require extra (ugly) work, since one has to fool the test for class ggplot... I reckon it will be easier to call `pdf() ; grid.draw(g); dev.off()` explicitly.

---

### Edit by Roland:

I made a small correction and wrapped it in a function:

```
facet_wrap_labeller <- function(gg.plot,labels=NULL) {
  #works with R 3.0.1 and ggplot2 0.9.3.1
  require(gridExtra)
  
  g <- ggplotGrob(gg.plot)
  gg <- g$grobs      
  strips <- grep("strip_t", names(gg))
    
  for(ii in seq_along(labels))  {
    modgrob <- getGrob(gg[[strips[ii]]], "strip.text", 
                       grep=TRUE, global=TRUE)
    gg[[strips[ii]]]$children[[modgrob$name]] <- editGrob(modgrob,label=labels[ii])
  }
  
  g$grobs <- gg
  class(g) = c("arrange", "ggplot",class(g)) 
  g
}
```

This allows to print nicely and even `ggsave` can be used.

Comment: Any idea how to change and save the grob, so that `ggsave` can be used?

Comment: @Roland, my alternative [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297155/add-floating-axis-labels-in-facet-wrap-plot/13316126#13316126) ("Edit 3") concerns this exact issue. `class(g) <- c("facetAdjust", "gtable", "ggplot")` and `print.facetAdjust` from my answer would help here.

Comment: @Roland if you use the gridExtra package, you can use `class(g) = c("arrange", "ggplot",class(g))` as the `print.arrange` method will work with `ggsave`.

Comment: `no applicable method for 'validGrob' applied to an object of class "c('arrange', 'gtable', 'ggplot')"`

Comment: strange, do you have gridExtra loaded?

Comment: Yes, I changed that inside the function.

Comment: I don't get this error, but took the opportunity to fix a typo you had in the function.

Comment: My bad, I missed one of the classes.

Comment: @Roland my labels are of the form K[12] or K[12:3] but your function doesn't give the parts in square brackets as subscripts? What could be missing?

Comment: @nstjhp Well, did you wrap your labels into `bquote` or `expression`?

Comment: @Roland I tried many combinations but presumably in the wrong place. When I tried expression in the label argument to editGrob then all I got was "ii" as subscript to "labels" for all facets (as could be expected I suppose). What is the correct way of wrapping the labels vector?

Comment: @nstjhp Please ask a new question (including a reproducible example).

Comment: Could the above solution be modified to work with two factors (i.e. facet_wrap(  ~ A + B)).

Answer (score 9):

As of `ggplot2` 2.1.0 `labeller` has been implemented for `facet_wrap`.

Answer (score 8):

Just came across this very useful function from roland and baptiste but needed a slightly different use case where the original wrap headers should be converted by a function rather than provided as a fixed value. I'm posting a slightly modified version of the original function in case it's useful to anybody else. It allows both the use of named (fixed value) expressions for the wrap strips, as well as use of custom functions and the functions already provided by ggplot2 for the `facet_grid` `labeller` parameter (such as `label_parsed` and `label_bquote`).

```
facet_wrap_labeller <- function(gg.plot, labels = NULL, labeller = label_value) {
  #works with R 3.1.2 and ggplot2 1.0.1
  require(gridExtra)

  # old labels
  g <- ggplotGrob(gg.plot)
  gg <- g$grobs      
  strips <- grep("strip_t", names(gg))
  modgrobs <- lapply(strips, function(i) {
    getGrob(gg[[i]], "strip.text", grep=TRUE, global=TRUE)
  })
  old_labels <- sapply(modgrobs, function(i) i$label)

  # find new labels
  if (is.null(labels)) # no labels given, use labeller function
    new_labels <- labeller(names(gg.plot$facet$facets), old_labels)
  else if (is.null(names(labels))) # unnamed list of labels, take them in order
    new_labels <- as.list(labels)
  else { # named list of labels, go by name where provided, otherwise keep old
    new_labels <- sapply(as.list(old_labels), function(i) {
      if (!is.null(labels[[i]])) labels[[i]] else i
    })
  }

  # replace labels
  for(i in 1:length(strips))  {
    gg[[strips[i]]]$children[[modgrobs[[i]]$name]] <- 
       editGrob(modgrobs[[i]], label=new_labels[[i]])
  }

  g$grobs <- gg
  class(g) = c("arrange", "ggplot",class(g))
  return(g) 
}
```

#### Update / warning

For newer versions of the `gridExtra` package you'll get the error `Error: No layers in plot` when running this function because `arrange` is no longer in `gridExtra` and R tries to interpret it as a `ggplot`. You can fix this by (re-)introducing the `print` function for the `arrange` class:

```
print.arrange <- function(x){
    grid::grid.draw(x)
}
```

This should now allow the plot to render and you can use `ggsave()` e.g. like so: `ggsave("test.pdf", plot = facet_wrap_labeller(p, labeller = label_parsed))`

#### Examples

A couple of use case examples:

```
# artificial data frame
data <- data.frame(x=runif(16), y=runif(16), panel = rep(c("alpha", "beta", "gamma","delta"), 4))
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~panel)

# no changes, wrap panel headers stay the same
facet_wrap_labeller(p) 

# replace each panel title statically
facet_wrap_labeller(p, labels = expression(alpha^1, beta^1, gamma^1, delta^1)) 

# only alpha and delta are replaced
facet_wrap_labeller(p, labels = expression(alpha = alpha^2, delta = delta^2)) 

# parse original labels
facet_wrap_labeller(p, labeller = label_parsed) 

# use original labels but modifying them via bquote
facet_wrap_labeller(p, labeller = label_bquote(.(x)^3)) 

# custom function (e.g. for latex to expression conversion)
library(latex2exp)
facet_wrap_labeller(p, labeller = function(var, val) { 
  lapply(paste0("$\\sum\\", val, "$"), latex2exp)
})
```

Comment: Hmmm. I'm getting `Error: No layers in plot` whenever I call the `facet_wrap_labeller` function. I'm loading the same version of ggplot2 (1.0.1)... although my R version is newer (3.2.2). Anyone else running into the same problem?

Comment: You are right, thanks for reporting. As far as I can tell, the problem is that the newest version of gridExtra (which you'll have gotten after installing R 3.2.2) no longer has the `arrange` class so it tries to plot as a `ggplot` but it's no longer a `ggplot`, it's already the `gtable`/`grob` object so it fails with the error message you observed. I don't know if there is a new way to do this using gridExtra, maybe @baptiste has an idea? For now, you can do the following: remove the line `class(g) = c("arrange", "ggplot",class(g))` and use `grid.arrange(facet_wrap_labeller(p))` on your plots

Comment: @Grant, scratch that, easier to just (re-)introduce `print.arrange`. I updated the answer accordingly, basically just add: `print.arrange <- function(x){
  grid::grid.draw(x)
}`

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to the other answers and comments for mentioning `label_parsed`.  It was still not really clear how to use the label parser so I add a simple reproducible example here.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Create a first facet variable with examples of math formulas
iris2 <- iris %>%
    mutate(species_math = factor(Species,
                            levels = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
                            labels = c("m^2",
                                       expression(bar(x) == sum(frac(x[i], n), i==1, n) * beta * Q[t-1]),
                                       bquote(pi == .(pi)))))

# Create a second facet variable with mean lengths
# This illustrates how to pass a numeric vector inside a formula
iris_mean <- iris2 %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(across(ends_with("Length"), mean), .groups="drop")

iris2$mean_length <- factor(iris2$Species,
                           levels =  c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
                           labels = mapply(function(p, s) bquote(bar(p) == .(p) ~ bar(s) ==.(s)),
                                            round(iris_mean$Petal.Length,3), round(iris_mean$Sepal.Length,3)))


iris2 %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(species_math ~ mean_length + Species, labeller = labeller(species_math = label_parsed, mean_length = label_parsed))

ggsave("~/downloads/formula_in_facet.png",
       width = 12, height = 8, units = "cm")
```

[image]

As shown in the example above, the labeller can parse:

1. A character vector such as "m^2" for simple formulas
2. An `expression` for more complex math with indices
3. The output of `bquote` to include numerical values in the formula. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58048944/2641825) on how to use `bquote` with numerical vectors of more than one value.
4. see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51863090/2641825) on how to  apply the labeller to one of the faceting variables only. In our case we apply it to the `species_math` variable only.

The syntax is different from Latex math formulas because `label_parsed` interprets labels as `plotmath` expressions. For example indices are written `x_i` in Latex and `x[i]` in plot math expressions, and Greek letters are written directly as `alpha` instead of `\alpha` in Latex. You can find many formulas in the help page of the  [plotmath](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) function. Good luck with the `plotmath` examples.