# Eliminate strip.background on one axis (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Many of the theme elements in ggplot2 have a .x or .y only extension to remove/alter something on only one axis.  `strip.background` does not have a `strip.background.x` equivalent as can be seen below.

**How can I remove the text and `strip.background` from the facet labels on only one axis?**

```
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(cyl~gear) 

a + theme(strip.text.y = element_blank(), 
    strip.background.x = element_blank())

##     > a + theme(strip.text.y = element_blank(), strip.background.x = element_blank())
##     Error in (function (el, elname)  : 
##       "strip.background.x" is not a valid theme element name.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least for the ggplot2 version 2.0.0. if you set the `strip.text.x=` or `strip.text.y=` to `element_blank()` it removes text and the background for particular axis.

```
a + theme(strip.text. = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cyl~gear) 

strip.remover <- function(ggp, what="x") {
  require(gridExtra)

  zeroGrob <- function() {
    g0 <- grob(name="NULL")
    class(g0) <- c("zeroGrob",class(g0))
    g0
  }

  g <- ggplotGrob(ggp)

  g$grobs <- lapply(g$grob, function(gr) {
    if (any(grepl(paste0("strip.text.", what),names(gr$children)))) {
      gr$children[[grep("strip.background",names(gr$children))]] <- zeroGrob()
      gr$children[[grep("strip.text",names(gr$children))]] <- zeroGrob()
    }
    return(gr)
  }
  )

  class(g) = c("arrange", "ggplot",class(g)) 
  g
}

strip.remover(a, "y")
```

[image]

Comment: I learned this from [@baptiste](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979017/changing-facet-label-to-math-formula-in-ggplot2#comment24535306_16964861).

Comment: even I think that you can simplify your "grobs  strip search"..it looks a little bit complicated..

Comment: @Rolan, very clever.  I think I like agstudy's a little more in that it is slightly simplier and does not rely on nonexported functions.

Comment: @TylerRinker The difference is that in his solution the strips are still there (only set to transparent).

Comment: Hmm, very true.  Is there a way to eliminate the need for `ggplot2:::zeroGrob`?  Maybe define the function ourselves?  I'm throwing this into a person use package: https://github.com/trinker/plotflow but if ever I did push to CRAN the `:::` is a no go.

Comment: @Roland even with `fill=NA` does the agstudy solution take up space?  The solutions appear identical?

Comment: I looked and the answer is yes.

Comment: @TylerRinker I define `zeroGrob()` inside the function now.

Comment: Perfect.  Exactly what I was after.

Comment: This approach no longer works after ggplot2 2.0 version

Comment: @TylerRinker Thank you for the notice. However, I simply can't update all my answers that break after package updates.

Comment: @Roland ageed wasnt sure how to handle it as I want other searchers to be able to find the best answer, which changed after the update.  I thought about a new question but that was a dupe.

Comment: Added a 50 point reward for original answer that is now obsolete after ggplot2 2.0

Comment: @TylerRinker Thanks, but that was really not necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way to remove the relevant strips,

```
library(grid)  # for the grid functions
g <- ggplotGrob(a)
keep <- !grepl("strip-right", g$layout$name)
g$grobs <- g$grobs[keep]
g$layout <- g$layout[keep, ]
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Answer (score 3):

Same idea but using `grid` package

```
g <- ggplotGrob(a)
gg <- g$grobs
strip_right.index <- which(grepl('strip-right',g$layout$name))
for(ii in strip_right.index)
  gg[[ii]] <- editGrob(getGrob(gg[[ii]],'strip.back'
                               ,grep=TRUE,global=TRUE)
                       ,gp = gpar(fill=NA))

g$grobs <- gg
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: But the panels will still be there, i.e., take up graph space, won't they? I think you could at least set `fill=NA`.

Comment: @Roland my mistake..I mean NA in fact.

Comment: @agstudy I think this solution is a bit more generalizable in that it doesn't rely on non exported functions.  Could you extend it to remove the other side as well (the x side)?

Answer (score 2):

In ggplot2 version 3.0.0 this works as you expected.
`theme(strip.background.x = element_blank())` is now a valid theme element name.

Citing from https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v3.0.0:

> Minor bug fixes and improvements
>
> Faceting
>
> You can now style the background of horizontal and vertical strips independently with
> strip.background.x and strip.background.y theme settings (#2249).

The underlying feature request can be found here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2249