# Removing strip.background on one axis: no layers

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

Some months ago, I needed to remove one of the strips generated by a ggplot2 faceted plot. I found that someone had already asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19063982/227103), and the answer worked pretty well:

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cyl~gear) 

strip.remover <- function(ggp, what="x") {
  require(gridExtra)

  zeroGrob <- function() {
    g0 <- grob(name="NULL")
    class(g0) <- c("zeroGrob",class(g0))
    g0
  }

  g <- ggplotGrob(ggp)

  g$grobs <- lapply(g$grob, function(gr) {
    if (any(grepl(paste0("strip.text.", what),names(gr$children)))) {
      gr$children[[grep("strip.background",names(gr$children))]] <- zeroGrob()
      gr$children[[grep("strip.text",names(gr$children))]] <- zeroGrob()
    }
    return(gr)
  }
  )

  class(g) = c("arrange", "ggplot",class(g)) 
  g
}

strip.remover(a, "y")
```

Today, I was trying to regenerate some figures that used this code and it didn't work to my surprise. Apparently, making a grob with `ggplotGrob`, modifying its contents and transforming it back to a `ggplot2` object does not work anymore.

I am a bit clueless on how to proceed here. Any ideas on why this code does not work anymore?

I suspect that the package `gridExtra` may be the culprit. In my work machine where this code works, this package is in version 0.9.1, but in my laptop, where it doesn't work, I have 2.0.0. Since the gap between versions is quite large, I have no idea what change may be related to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** Setting `strip.text.x` or `strip.text.y` to `element_blank()` completely removes the strip.

```
library(ggplot2)

a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cyl~gear)

a + theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

**Original**
A point to note: ggplot grobs can't be transformed back into ggplot2 objects. But ggplot grobs can be made to behave a bit like a ggplot2 object.

Another point: In the link you provide, look down the list of solutions to Baptiste's solution. It is less dependent on the structure of the ggplot grob.

```
library(ggplot2)

a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cyl~gear) 

library(grid)

# To remove the strip but keep the space
g <- ggplotGrob(a)
keep <- !grepl("strip-r", g$layout$name)
g$grobs <- g$grobs[keep]
g$layout <- g$layout[keep, ]
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)

# To remove the strip and the space
g = g[, -which(!keep)]
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

To make the grob behave more like a ggplot object:

```
#  A print method for the plot
print.ggplotgrob <- function(x) {
   grid.newpage()   
   grid.draw(x)
}
class(g) = c("ggplotgrob", class(g)) 

g
ggsave("plotGrob.png", g)
```

**OR** Wrap it up in a function:

```
strip.remover = function(plot, strip) {
    g <- ggplotGrob(plot); dev.off()
    if(!(strip == "t" | strip == "r") )  stop("strip must be either 't' or 'r'")

    keep <- !grepl(paste0("strip-", strip), g$layout$name)
    g$grobs <- g$grobs[keep]
    g$layout <- g$layout[keep, ]

    class(g) <- c("ggplotgrob",  class(g)) 
    g
}

#  A print method for the plot
print.ggplotgrob <- function(x) {
    library(grid)
    grid.newpage()   
    grid.draw(x)
    }


# Try it out
gtplot <- strip.remover(a, "t")
gtplot
ggsave("grob.png", gtplot)

strip.remover(a, "r")
strip.remover(a, "wrong")
```

Comment: Excellent answer. So, in future versions of ggplot (>1.0.1) there is no ggplot class?

Comment: Not quite.  Currently, `ggsave` checks for a `ggplot` object. The ggplot grob (i.e., the object after `ggplotGrob (a)` ) is a gtable object but not a ggplot object, and hence ggsave fails. In the next version of ggplot, ggsave will save gtables.