# What are the differences in use of labeller as function and as argument in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have solved my particular use case issue regarding this, but I hope that by posing this question I may assist others with similar issues and provide a bookmark to come back to in the future if I need to make similar graphics. When using `library(ggplot2)` the capability to facet plots into multi-panel figures is paramount to many analyses, however, getting the labels right using the `labeller` argument and/or function can be rather finicky when the underlying data is not formatted correctly. I present to you a simple data set to demonstrate my particular use case and some variations that caused me problems, as well as the solutions that I used. I also pose some questions about how the `labeller` function is used within the `labeller` argument to `facet_wrap` and/or `facet_grid`. The starting data:

```
dat <- tibble(label1 = c('one','two','three','four','five','six',
                         'six','five','four','three','two','one'),
              label2 = rep('T[alpha]'),
              fit = c(25,50,75,40,60,90,40,50,70,30,90,100),
              upr = c(35,60,85,50,70,100,50,60,80,40,100,110),
              lwr = c(15,40,65,30,50,80,30,40,60,20,80,90),
              var1 = rep(c(seq(1990,1995,1)),2))
```

Notice that `label2` here is a character expression that can be evaluated as an expression. This appears to be the same as using base-R to plot:

```
plot(dat$var1, dat$fit)
mtext(expression(paste('T'[alpha])))
```

Essentially, as long as the expression can be evaluated within the expression function, it will work with `label_parsed` as an argument to `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`. Here is what the code looks like for the actual plot I want:

```
p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = var1, y = fit)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = var1, y = lwr, yend = upr)) +
  facet_grid(label1~label2, scales =  "fixed", 
             labeller = label_parsed) 

p1
```

Now if I want to use `label1` with a space, I can use this solution as well, but need to include a tilde `~` anywhere the space should exist so that it is still able to be evaluated as an expression.

```
dat1 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(label1 = paste(label1, '~x', sep = ''))

dat1

p2 <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x = var1, y = fit)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = var1, y = lwr, yend = upr)) +
  facet_grid(label1~label2, scales =  "fixed", 
             labeller = label_parsed)

p2
```

This is as far as I had to go to solve my use case. Howver, to better understand the functionality I would like to ask the community to clarify another way of using labeller as a function. The question posed here:
[label_parsed of facet_grid in ggplot2 mixed with spaces and expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269122/label-parsed-of-facet-grid-in-ggplot2-mixed-with-spaces-and-expressions/51863090?noredirect=1#comment125048937_51863090)
eventually helped me arrive at my solution. However, if we use the code as written in that question, where the labeller argument is: `labeller = labeller(type=label_parsed)` the result is not what is desired (we get the character expression as written instead of being evaluated as an expression.

```
p3 <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x = var1, y = fit)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = var1, y = lwr, yend = upr)) +
  facet_grid(label1~label2, scales =  "fixed", 
             labeller = labeller(type=label_parsed)) # this is the change

p3
```

Can anyone explain when it would be appropriate to use `labeller` as a function within the call to `labeller` from `facet_grid`? My hope is that a solution exists that doesn't require re-formatting of the entire dataset to reflect expressions and perhaps that utility lies within the labeller function itself.

Comment: `labeller` doesn't have a `type=` parameter. It's meant for you to use name of the columns that you want to change. Perhaps you want `labeller = labeller(label2=label_parsed)` since that's the one that contains the expressions.

Comment: @ Mr. Flick Thank you that works. And this also will work to update only a single label. Using this I could also use `labeller = labeller(label2=label_parsed, label1=label_value)` which is immensely helpful and prevents the need for changing underlying data if it not necessary!