# R shared legend error

Tags: r, plot, structure, legend, shared

[image: Please click here to see the image]

I'm using a shared legend in R, which is using this code:

```
g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position="bottom"))$grobs
  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
```

Reference: [Combining grid_arrange_shared_legend() and facet_wrap_labeller() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370203/combining-grid-arrange-shared-legend-and-facet-wrap-labeller-in-r)

What is "structure(c(3L,3L,……))" in my legend? How to avoid it?

My code:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

wq <- read.csv('wineQualityReds.csv')
quality_factor <- factor(wq$quality)

plot_three <- function(feature) {
    ggplot(data=wq, 
           aes_string(x = feature, y = wq$pH, color = quality_factor)) + 
    geom_tile() + 
    scale_color_brewer(palette='Blues') +
    geom_smooth(method = loess, aes(group = 1)) + theme(legend.position = "none")
}
ph1 <- plot_three("volatile.acidity")  +  
  labs(x='volatile.acidity(g / dm^3)', y='pH')

ph2 <- plot_three("citric.acid")  +  
  labs(x='citric.acid(g / dm^3)', y='pH')

ph3 <- plot_three("chlorides")  +  
  labs(x='chlorides(g / dm^3)', y='pH')

ph4 <- plot_three("free.sulfur.dioxide")  +  
  labs(x='free.sulfur.dioxide(mg / dm^3)', y='pH')

ph5 <- plot_three("sulphates")  +  
  labs(x='sulphates(g / dm^3)', y='pH')

ph6 <- plot_three("alcohol")  +  
  labs(x='alcohol(% by volume)', y='pH')

g <- ggplotGrob(ph1 + theme(legend.position="bottom"))$grobs
legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(ph1, ph2, ph3, ph4, ph5, ph6, ncol =3), 
legend, top = "Relationship between pH and features via different quality", heights=c(9,1))
```

Dataset: redwineQuality

https://s3.amazonaws.com/udacity-hosted-downloads/ud651/wineQualityReds.csv

Comment: Please open the picture by clicking the hypolink "name". Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: please provide a reproducible code