# Adding expressions to facet labeller in ggplot 2 2.0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to replace one facet wrap label with a complicated expression. However, i cannot get the function [facet_wrap_labeller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979017/changing-facet-label-to-math-formula-in-ggplot2) to work anymore with plots created under older ggplot2 versions.

```
        data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(60),20,3)) 
        data$factor <- c(rep("f1", 4),rep("f2", 4), rep("f3", 4), rep("f4",4),rep("f5", 4))
        names(data) <- c("A", "B", "C", "factor")
        melted <- melt(data)

        p <- ggplot(melted, aes(variable, value)) +
             stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + 
             geom_boxplot()
        p1 <- p + facet_wrap(~factor)
        facet_wrap_labeller(p1, labels=c("A", "B", expression({}^2*italic(D)~textstyle(group("(", rarefied, ")")))))
```

and i get:

```
Error in getGrob(gg[[strips[ii]]], "strip.text", grep = TRUE, global = TRUE) : 
  it is only valid to get a child from a "gTree"
Called from: getGrob(gg[[strips[ii]]], "strip.text", grep = TRUE, global = TRUE)
```

I believe this is happening because of ggplot2 2.0 not being compatible to this function.

I also tried the `labeller=labeller()`, and `labeller=bquote()` arguments, but when i tried to use this vector

```
newlabels <- c(A="A", B="B",,
    D=expression({}^0*italic(D)~textstyle(group("(", rarefied, ")"))))
```

in

```
p1 <- p + facet_wrap(~factor, 
           labeller = labeller(factor=newlabels))
```

the expression is ignored and the original factor levels are plotted. With bquote, i dont know to add more than one name to the argument.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There only appear to be 4 labels for 5 facets in your example, but you could use `labeller=label_parsed` and rename the factor levels fairly easily, avoiding the need for another function.

```
## Rename levels (I used data.table::melt, so they were characters)
melted$factor <- factor(melted$factor, 
                        levels=paste0('f', 1:5),
                        labels=c('A', 'B', 'C', '{}^0*italic(D)~plain((rarefied))', 'E'))

p <- ggplot(melted, aes(variable, value)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + 
  geom_boxplot()
p + facet_wrap(~factor, labeller=label_parsed)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so far. I get Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated after data.table::melt.

Comment: And then the plot is not drawn due to Error in panel_scales(panels, data$PANEL[1]) : 
  invalid type/length (environment/1) in vector allocation
In addition: Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated

Comment: got it to work, just a thinly veiled typing mistake :)