# R : ggplot2 : facet_grid : how include math expressions in few (not all) labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I get stuck with something on `ggplot2`. I read most of the related posts, tried things but did not find any real solution.

I want to include mathematical expressions in the label of my `facet_grids` with `ggplot2`.

- In the raw file, I cannot write the name µg.L-1
- In the titles and axis I can do it, for example :
  `qplot(day, activity, data=a) +xlab(expression("100 µg "*.L^"-1"*""))` : this is working well.
- How do I do for the facet_labels ? 
  I can set the levels and rename the labels factors but the expression is not taken into account, for example :

  `levels(a$group) <- c("control", expression("100 µg "*.L^"-1"*""))`

  `qplot(…, facets=~group)`

Results :

> Label of facet 1 is written on the graph : control
>
> Label of facet 2 is written on the graph :  "100 µg "*.L^"-1"*""  …

and I don’t want that.

I don’t want to use `facet_grid(.~group, labeller=label_bquote(…))` because I don’t want all my labels to follow the same expression. I want to edit the labels one by one **manually**…
I tried with `bquote(…)` instead of `expression(…)` but the same bad result happens

Does someone have any clue with this?

---

An example: I define a dataframe :

```
activity<- as.numeric(c("44","41","48","43","42","45","44","39", "47", "68", "88", "57"))
group<-c("first","first","first","first","first","first",
         "second","second","second","second","second","second")
day<- c("0", "0", "0", "20","20", "20","0", "0", "0", "20","20", "20" )
a<-data.frame(activity, group, day)
```

I plot :

```
require (ggplot2)
```

`qplot(day, activity, facets=.~group, data=a, ylim=c(25,90))`

[image]

I want to change the name of the facet labels and the y axis :

```
levels(a$group)<- c("control", expression("100 µg "*.L^"-1"*""))
qplot(day, activity, facets=.~group, data=a, ylim=c(25,90),
  ylab=expression("fmol "*.µl^"-1"*""))
```

[image]

It works well with the y-axis, however for the facet label, it does not work...
Any clue ?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a more [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data we can copy/paste into R to re-create the problem.

Comment: Paul - check out this post "Changing facet label to math formula in ggplot2" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979017/changing-facet-label-to-math-formula-in-ggplot2

Comment: @MrFlick : thank you, see below for more details...

Comment: @Technophobe01 : thank you, i saw this post but could not figure out how to do in my context...

Comment: does this work: `ggplot(a, aes(day, activity)) + facet_grid(.~group, labeller= label_parsed)`

Comment: @paul - In reference to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979017/changing-facet-label-to-math-formula-in-ggplot2, the important details are in the last two entries. i.e. # parse original labels facet_wrap_labeller(p, labeller = label_parsed) and "As of ggplot2 2.1.0 labeller has been implemented for facet_wrap.".  Apologies, I should have been more explicit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Proposed Solution:

Prequisite:

```
activity <- as.numeric(c("44", "41", "48", "43", "42", "45", 
  "44", "39", "47", "68", "88", "57"))
group <- c("first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
  "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second")
day <- c("0", "0", "0", "20", "20", "20", "0", "0", "0", "20", 
  "20", "20")
a <- data.frame(activity, group, day)
require(ggplot2)
levels(a$group) <- c("control", expression("100 µg " * .L^"-1" * ""))
```

Proposed Solution:

```
p1 <- qplot(day, activity, data = a)
p1 + facet_grid(. ~ group, labeller = label_parsed)
```

result:

[image]

### Explanation

We create the labels structure as a string, where we create a formula, noting to use `~` to replace spaces... We then tell `facet_grid()` to parse the label string passed to it as a formula by setting `labeller = label_parsed`...

Note: The details of the display are described in `?plotmath`, but note that `geom_text()` and `facet_grid()` use strings, not expressions.

I hope the above helps.

#### Reference:

See Hagley Wickham's page on labellers...: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/labeller

Comment: Thank you so much, it is exactly was i was looking for and it works perfectly. I thought the "label_parsed" was putting all the label in the same math expression, but it actually "analyses" the grammar structure...  Thank you ;)

Comment: Great - Paul can you please mark as answered. (Tick this solved your problem.) That will help others find it.

Comment: this is awesome... also works with `bquote()`, e.g., `factor( df$measure, levels = c("area", "length"), labels = c(bquote(area ~~ (cm^2)), bquote(length ~~ (cm))))`

Comment: Current labeller docs: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labeller.html

Answer (score 11):

You can use label_parsed, provided all your labels are valid expressions (you can put text inside quotes if necessary)

```
library(ggplot2) 
levels(a$group)<- c("'control test'", "100~mu*g*'.L'^-1")
ggplot(a) + facet_grid(.~group, labeller=label_parsed)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, label_parsed was exactly what i was looking for but i did not understand how to handle it properly... thanks ;)