# ggplot2: how to use facet_wrap_labeller to get correct subscripts

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

This question refers to, and requires (but maybe not?), the function `facet_wrap_labeller` written by Roland here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16964861/3275826

MWE for my case:

```
dput(test)
structure(list(V1 = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.1, 3.67, 3.73, 
3.79, 3.85, 3.91, 3.97), V2 = c(0.0291598, 3.40333, 1.3881, 0.15733, 
0.0200618, 0.00145373, 0.332262, 0.30233, 0.288497, 0.267876, 
0.264134, 0.227544), V3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("Param0", "Param1", 
"Param2", "Param3", "Param4", "Param5", "Param6", "Param7", "Param8", 
"Param9", "Param10", "Param11", "Param12", "Param13", "Param14", 
"Param15", "Param16", "Param17", "Param18"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 945L, 946L, 
947L, 948L, 949L, 950L), class = "data.frame")

dput(testLabels)
structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("K[12:3]", "K[12]"), class = "factor")

## Will shows Param0 in the strip but this is modified by the facet_wrap_labeller
pp = ggplot(test, aes(x=test$V1)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0,ymax=test$V2), fill="blue",  alpha=0.2, colour="blue") + facet_wrap(~V3, scales="free", ncol=3)
facet_wrap_labeller(pp, testLabels)
```

Problem: Facet strip labels are non-trivial to manipulate when using facet_wrap. In my case the plot shows K[12:3] etc rather than the [12:3] as a subscript as I would like.

I like Roland's function but I don't know how to adapt it for the case where your label subscripts are not just integers.
A solution can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6539953/3275826 however I would like to know how to adapt the aforementioned function as I have a lot of these instances.

Someone who is more confident than me with "computing on the language" could help, but perhaps I am overcomplicating the problem? Using `R 3.0.2` and `ggplot2_0.9.3.1`.

Comment: You can use Roland's function with `facet_wrap_labeller(pp, expression(K[12], K[12:3]))`

Comment: or change this in the function `editGrob(modgrob,label=parse(text=labels[ii]))`

Comment: Thanks both. If one of you can write a short answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Which one worked for you, nstjhp? I'm trying to use the same function, but it doesn't seem to be modifying the labels. Cheers.

Comment: @meep actually both worked for me. Checking back through my old code shows I used baptiste's solution as I had lots of these "K[x:y]" things.