# Displaying a greater than or equal sign

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

I have a plot which is generated thus:

```
ggplot(dt.2, aes(x=AgeGroup, y=Prevalence)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), colour="black", width=.2) +
    geom_point(size=2, colour="Red")
```

I control the x axis labels like this:

```
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("0-29","30-49","50-64","65-79",">80","All")) +
```

This works but I need to change the ">80" label to "≥80".

However "≥80" is displayed as "=80".

How can I display the greater than or equal sign ?

Comment: @JanDvorak, unfortunately not. It's for publication, so it needs to look as good as possible. I wanted to go with >79 but the senior authors specifically wants ≥80

Comment: have you tried `expression("">=80)`? See `?plotmath`.

Comment: @plannapus - that does the trick nicely ! Thank you - if you make an answer, I will upvote and accept...

Comment: It seems that @mnel was quicker than me :)

Comment: I posted before I saw your comment (if that makes it better?)

Comment: And I saw your answer just as I posted my comment!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

An alternative to using expressions is Unicode characters, in this case Unicode Character 'GREATER-THAN OR EQUAL TO' (U+2265). Copying @mnel's example

```
.d <- data.frame(a = letters[1:6], y = 1:6)

ggplot(.d, aes(x=a,y=y)) + geom_point() + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c(letters[1:5], "\u2265 80"))
```

Unicode is a good alternative if you have trouble remembering the complicated expression syntax or if you need linebreaks, which expressions don't allow. As a downside, whether specific Unicode characters work at all depends on your graphics device and font of choice.

Comment: Problem: the `pdf` device does not support this character and prints ... instead. I'm not working in `ggplot` so maybe this isn't a concern in that package, but it's troublesome for saving from base R.

Comment: @MichaelChirico: Solution: unless you have compelling reason to use `pdf`, use `cairo_pdf` instead.

Comment: can you give an example of what such a compelling reason might be?

Comment: @otsaw I have the same problem with the `postscript` device for producing eps. Is there a `cairo_postscript` or similiar solution that you know of?

Comment: Works within a call to `paste`, so that's nice!

Comment: [This wikipedia site lists all mathematical operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode)- some of the more common ones are listed at the bottom of the site!

Comment: And [this blog](https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2017/09/27/working-with-r-cairo-graphics-custom-fonts-and-ggplot/) gives helpful advice how to use cairo with `ggsave`

Comment: how can we do lower that or equal sign?

Comment: FYI this also works for the `forestplot` package, for anyone who's just been googling a similarissue!

Answer (score 23):

You can pass an expression (including `phantom(...)` to fake a leading `>=` within
the `label` argument to `scale_x_discrete(...)`

for example

```
 .d <- data.frame(a = letters[1:6], y = 1:6)

 ggplot(.d, aes(x=a,y=y)) + geom_point() + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c(letters[1:5], expression(phantom(x) >=80))
```

[image]

See `?plotmath` for more details on creating mathematical expressions and
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2)  related SO question and answer

Answer (score 13):

```
plot(5, ylab=expression("T ">="5"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
expression("">=80)
```

So your full axis label like would look like:

```
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("0-29","30-49","50-64","65-79",expression("">=80),"All")) +
```

I have had trouble exporting plots when using unicode, but the expression function is more consistent.

EDIT: Coming back to this years later, the `expression` solution is really nice because it also allows you to include both numbers and text, e.g.,

```
expression("">="80 years old")
```