# Multi line title in ggplot 2 with multiple italicized words

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create a **plot title** manually formatted on **two lines** which includes **two italicized words**, I have done some [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223846/ggplot2-two-line-label-with-expression)
on Stack Exchange but have not found a good solution to this seemingly simple problem.

The scientific names of the two species are fairly long, and thus the need for a multi-line title (ggplot2 doesn't format this).

Objective:

> ..........First Line of Title with *Species*
>
> Second line words *anotherItalicSpecies* the end

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title= expression(paste(atop("First line of title with ", atop((italic("Species")))),"
       secondline words", italic("anotherSpecies"), "the end")))
```

Which yields the following mangled title:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using a combination of `atop`, `paste`, `italic` and `scriptstyle`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = ~ atop(paste('First line of title with ',italic("Species")),
                      paste(scriptstyle(italic("Species")),
                            scriptstyle(" secondline words "),
                            scriptstyle(italic("anotherSpecies")),
                            scriptstyle(" the end"))))
```

gives you the desired result:

[image]

Using `scriptstyle` is not a necessity, but imho it is nicer to have your subtitle in a smaller font than the main title.

See also `?plotmath` for other usefull customizations.

Comment: Could this solution possibly align the title to the left of the plot?

Comment: @user7395965 not completely; if you want that, it is better to use Henrik's solutions

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to inserting line breaks in `title`, you may use `title` together with `subtitle` (available from `ggplot 2.2.0`). Possibly this makes the `plothmath`ing slightly more straightforward.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = expression("First line: "*italic("Honorificabilitudinitatibus")),
       subtitle = expression("Second line: "*italic("Honorificabilitudinitatibus praelongus")*" and more"))
p
```

[image]

---

If you wish the font size to be the same on both lines, set the desired `size` in `theme`.

```
p + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12))
```

Note that both title and subtitle are left-aligned by default in `ggplot2 2.2.0`. The text can be centered by adding `hjust = 0.5` to `element_text` above.

Comment: Nice, I was just thinking about including these improvements from the development version in my answer ;-)

Comment: Haha :-) (plus plus too). Anyway, apparently ggplot was updated last week, didn't notice that :-/. Good to have both options.

Comment: Have upgraded, nice solution! but now I am receiving an error from the y-aesthetic in geom_ribbon... Appears to be related to ggplot 2.2.0. I'll do some searching, but do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Arch If you are running into a new problem, it is better to post a new question imo.

Answer (score 2):

We could also call `cowplot::draw_label()` two times (inspired from [this](https://github.com/stefano-meschiari/latex2exp/issues/11#issuecomment-441577714) discussion). However, we need to tweak a bit the position and make enough space for the custom title. I gave more explanations about this approach and also using `ggplot2::annotation_custom()` in [ggplot2 two-line label with expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54183969/5193830).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'cowplot'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     ggsave

# The two lines we wish on the plot. The ~~ creates extra space between the
# expression's components, might be needed here.
line_1 <- expression("First Line of Title with" ~~ italic("Species"))
line_2 <- expression(italic("Species") ~~ "second line words" ~~ italic("anotherSpecies") ~~ "the end")

# Make enough space for the custom two lines title
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "") + # empty title
  # Force a wider top margin to make enough space
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, # also adjust text size if needed
                                  margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0,
                                                  unit = "mm")))

# Call cowplot::draw_label two times to plot the two lines of text
ggdraw(p) +
  draw_label(line_1, x = 0.55, y = 0.97) +
  draw_label(line_2, x = 0.55, y = 0.93)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>