# How to italicize part (one or two words) of x-axis labels using multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis-labels, typography

(This is my first question on this forum, sorry in advance if it's not that clear!)

I am trying to rename the labels of the x axis of a graph made with ggplot2 in a way that:

1. it appears on two lines, and
2. some of the characters are in italic.

I have found two answers to help me with this problem, the first regarding italic in titles ([How to italicize part (one or two words) of an axis title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555531/how-to-italicize-part-one-or-two-words-of-an-axis-title?answertab=votes#tab-top)), the second regarding writing titles on two lines ([Add line break to axis labels and ticks in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123147/add-line-break-to-axis-labels-and-ticks-in-ggplot)).

Unfortunetaly, when I try those two solutions together, it doesn't work.

My case is a bit complex, so let me show you a simple analogous example, using the mtcars dataset.

**Here's the base code:**

```
base <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:20) +
  xlab(NULL)

base
```

**Which gives this:**
[Base graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKsZd.png)

**What I want is this (I completed it in Paint):** [Desired graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN9dG.png)

**The best I can do, based on my findings, is this:**

```
addline_format <- function(x,...){
  gsub('\\s','\n',x) 
  }

my_x_titles <- c(expression(paste("4 cylinders (", italic("N"), " = 11)")),
                 expression(paste("6 cylinders (", italic("N"), " = 7)")),
                 expression(paste("8 cylinders (", italic("N"), " = 14)")))

base + scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(4, 6, 8),
                        labels = addline_format(my_x_titles))
```

**Which gives something not great:** [My not-great solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czosc.png)

Using the homemade *addline_format* function seems to block the effect the *italic* function. Moreover, I'd like the labels to be on only two lines (please refer to my Desired solution picture), not multiple, even though I use multiple spaces.

Anyone would know how to solve this?

Comment: https://github.com/clauswilke/ggtext

Comment: I think package **ggtext** will make all of this much easier, but in the past the answer for italicized text plus line breaks has been to use `atop()`.  It works, but not always exactly how we want it to.  See some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720387/multi-line-title-in-ggplot-2-with-multiple-italicized-words/40720451#40720451) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490331/combining-new-lines-and-italics-in-facet-labels-with-ggplot2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cheat using `atop`:

```
my_x_titles <- c(
  expression(atop(paste("4 cylinders"), (italic(N) == 11))),
  expression(atop(paste("6 cylinders"), (italic(N) == 7))),
  expression(atop(paste("8 cylinders"), (italic(N) == 14)))
)

base + scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(4, 6, 8),
                        labels = my_x_titles)
```

Comment: Awesome, I like your cheat: it solved my problem right away!