# Align two line legend title to the left with expression()

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Using this script

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, color = letters[1:5])
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = color)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, pch = 21) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(
     title = expression(atop(Median~Nitrate-Nitrogen~(NO[3]^{textstyle("-")}-N), ".\n Concentration"~(mg~L^{textstyle("-")})))))
```

I got this figure

[image]

Any suggestions how to align the second line of the legend title to the left?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223846/ggplot2-two-line-label-with-expression

Comment: @akrun
I don't think so.

Comment: @akrun
Thanks. I appreciate that.

Comment: `theme(legend.title.align = 0)` seems only to have effect on "normal" two line legend titles but not with expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

quick and ugly answer but it does the job until someone post better...

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = color)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, pch = 21) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(
    title = expression(atop(Median~Nitrate-Nitrogen~(NO[3]^{textstyle("-")}-N), "Concentration"~(mg~L^{textstyle("-")})~phantom (1000000)~phantom (1000000)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help