# How to align the legend box to the middle of legend title in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

By default the legend box/key is aligned to the left of the legend title. Since I have quite long legend title, I want to align it to the center instead. I have tried `theme` and `guide_legend` without any success. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

- Data

  ```
  df <- structure(list(Flow = c(0.992762, 0.802408, 0.9826, 0.754863, 
          0.174542, 0.056777), Coef = c(0.62, 0.49, 0.38, 0.59, 0.25, 0.67
          ), VeryLongLegendTitle = c(4.47680710313542, 18.8500193246859, 
          5.82742564783431, 23.3217237977105, 13.0155332302148, 88.4960885143824
          )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("Flow", 
          "Coef", "VeryLongLegendTitle"))
  ```
- Code

  ```
  library(ggplot2)
  p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Flow, y = Coef, color = VeryLongLegendTitle)) +
    xlab(NULL) + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.0, 1.0), breaks = c(0.25, 0.75)) +
    geom_point(size = 2, alpha = 0.8) + 
    theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5))
  p1

  p1 + theme(legend.title.align = 0.5) 
  p1 + theme(legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  p1 + guides(color = guide_legend(title.hjust = 0.5))
  ```
- Plot
  [image]

Comment: Would you consider a horizontal legend instead? It seems like trying do this vertically would be unnecessarily complicated, not to mention a waste of graph space.

Comment: @www: I would if I only need one single plot. However my final plot consists of about 16 (4x4) small individual plots. Each row of the plot has different legend. Placing the legends on right is my only choice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrow the solution from this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48011882/786542)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)

long1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Flow, y = Coef, color = VeryLongLegendTitle)) +
  xlab(NULL) + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.0, 1.0), breaks = c(0.25, 0.75)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, alpha = 0.8) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5))

# extract legend
g <- ggplotGrob(long1)
grobs <- g$grobs
legend_index <- which(sapply(grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
legend <- grobs[[legend_index]]

# extract guides table
guides_index <- which(sapply(legend$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "layout")
guides <- legend$grobs[[guides_index]]

# add extra column for spacing
# guides$width[5] is the extra spacing from the end of the legend text
# to the end of the legend title. If we instead distribute it 50:50 on
# both sides, we get a centered legend
guides <- gtable_add_cols(guides, 0.5*guides$width[5], 1)
guides$widths[6] <- guides$widths[2]
title_index <- guides$layout$name == "title"
guides$layout$l[title_index] <- 2

# reconstruct legend and write back
legend$grobs[[guides_index]] <- guides
g$grobs[[legend_index]] <- legend

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @www but you can try `p1 + guides(color = guide_legend(keywidth = 5, keyheight = 2))`. It will produce something like this:
[image]

It would also be good to have a look at the [Legend guide](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I looked at that one and [`theme`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) already. Strange that there's such an option in `ggplot2`

Comment: You're welcome! You can also [put the title on two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154922/align-two-line-legend-title-to-the-left-with-expression).

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately the legend is just a single pretty long word

Comment: FYI there is a workaround using `gtable` I've just added as an answer