# expression function and line break (\n) error in bar labels of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression

I am trying to label my bars with labels that include one italicized letter and line breaks.

When I use the expression function to successfully italicize one letter of my labels, I get this weird effect where the line break (\n) makes the bar labels move above the x-axis and the alignment of the labels becomes staggered rather than centered.

Any help on successfully labeling my bars with one italicized letter and line breaks would be greatly appreciated.

```
# transform mtcars to look more like my data
mtcars$trans <- factor(mtcars$am, labels = c("auto", "manual"))
mtcars$origin <- factor(mtcars$cyl, labels = c("JPN", "GER", "USA"))

# create a data frame of means, SEs, and bar label variable (e.g., predictor)
d <- Rmisc::summarySE(subset(mtcars, origin !='USA'), 'mpg', c('trans', 'origin'))
d$predictor <- with(d, paste(trans, origin, sep='\n+\n'))

# Create expression list of bar labels with one letter italicized
ital_labels <- expression(
            paste("auto\n+\n", italic("J"), "PN"),   
            paste("auto\n+\n", italic("G"), "ER"),   
            paste("manual\n+\n", italic("J"), "PN"), 
            paste("manual\n+\n", italic("G"), "ER")
            )

# Plot it
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=predictor, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=trans), 
       position=position_dodge(),
       stat="identity", colour="black", size=0) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mpg-se, ymax=mpg+se), 
            size=.4, width=.1, position=position_dodge(9)) + 
  scale_x_discrete("\n(Error bars represent standard errors)",
               labels = ital_labels) + 
  ylab("\nMiles per Gallon\n")
```

Comment: Have you tried `atop` as shown, e.g., [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13225241/2461552)?

Comment: Thank you @aosmith! atop does work for the line break.