# ggplot two lines of title

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
gg <- ggplot(data = data, aes(Type1Error_v, power_v, color = factor(test))) + 
  geom_line(alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) +
  labs(title = expression(paste(H[0], ": BN with ", mu[1], "=10, ", mu[2], "=11, ", sigma[1]^2, "=1, ", sigma[2]^2, "=50.23, ", rho, "=0.8, ", "N=50, p=10%, t~Exp(0.1)")), 
       x = "False Positive Rate (Type I Error Rate)", 
       y = "True Positive Rate (Power)") + 
  xlim(0, 1)
```

Is there a way to make the title in two lines? atop and \n both doesn't work here.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of [ggplot2 two-line label with expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223846/ggplot2-two-line-label-with-expression)? Various solutions are proposed in that post.

Comment: it doesn't work for my case

Comment: *What* doesn't work? Please be specific. There are quite a few different approaches.

Comment: Because there are mu[1], sigma[1], etc. at different places, I cannot  use atop or \n.

Comment: There are other options given in that post. Not all use `"\n"` or `atop`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `expression` is to use `ggtext` (which requires `ggplot >= 3.3.0`); with `ggtext` you can format your title using HTML tags.

Here is an example:

```r
library(ggtext)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle("H<sub>0</sub>: BN with &mu;<sub>1</sub>=10, &mu;<sub>2</sub>=11; &sigma;<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>=1, &sigma;<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>=50.23<br>Another line with more text") +
    theme(plot.title = element_markdown())
```

Here `<sub>` defines subscript, `<sup>` is for superscript, `<br>` introduces a line-break, and so on.

[image]