# Using str_wrap() in conjunction with expression() to get a custom caption to fit under the plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, stringr

I am trying to create a custom caption to fit under my plot such that a portion of the caption text should be bold and the other part plain.  At the same time, I would like the caption to wrap so that the caption is not truncated.

```
cap <- expression(paste('\"', bold("This text should be bold"), ' This text should not be bold, but should be plain? And everything should fit under the plot\"'))
```

Here is my first attempt.  As one can see, the bold text appears correctly; however, the caption text is truncated at the plot border on the right.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x=wt, y=mpg))+
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 14))+
  labs(caption = cap)
```

[image]

In the second attempt, I used stringr::str_wrap so that the text is no longer truncated; however, the expression is not evaluated and so the caption is incorrect.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x=wt, y=mpg))+
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 14))+
  labs(caption = str_wrap(cap))
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to reconcile this problem? That is, I would like the caption to both evaluate so that it appears correctly, and also wrap.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expression` can't render linebreaks. You can get two lines with the [`atop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13225241/496488) function, but the relatively new [`ggtext`](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext) package is much more flexible. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

cap2 <- "<b>This text should be bold.</b> This text should not be bold, but should be plain? And everything should fit under the plot"

ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  labs(caption = cap2) +
  theme(plot.caption=element_textbox_simple(hjust=0, size=14))
```

[image]