# Two line x-axis label with greek letters and count

Tags: r, unicode, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a two line x-axis label with a variable name which contains a Greek letter and the count for my boxplot graph (example: α helix\n n=1000), similar to the accepted answer from this post:

[Combining `expression()` with `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198170/combining-expression-with-n)

I got the line break and Greek letters to work using  bquote and atop, but there is a gap between the label and count, so I would prefer to use the unicode method described in the referenced post.

```
a <- runif(500)
b <- runif(500)
c <- c(a, b)

variable <- factor(rep(1:3, c(1000, 500, 500 ))) #combined, helix, loop
protein  <- factor(rep(letters[1:3], c(1000, 500, 500))) #protA, protB, protC (there are different counts of each protein type for each variable, but I couldn't figure out how to generate that).  

mydata <- data.frame(variable, c(a,b,c))
names(mydata) <- c("variable", "value")
mydata$prot <- as.character(protein)
mydata.stat<-boxplot(value~variable, data=mydata, plot=FALSE)
mydata.n<-mydata.stat$n
count1 <- mydata.n[1]
count2 <- mydata.n[2]
count3 <- mydata.n[3]
xlab1 <-bquote(atop("combined", "(n="*.(count1)*")"))
xlab2 <-bquote(atop(alpha*" helix", "(n="*.(count2)*")"))
xlab3 <-bquote(atop(beta*alpha*" loops", "(n="*.(count3)*")"))

p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=(variable)))
p <- p + geom_boxplot(notch=addnotch, outlier.size=0, fill = NA, col = 
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(labels=c(xlab1, xlab2, xlab3))
ggsave(p, file="boxplot.pdf" , device=cairo_pdf, width=8, height=8)
```

[boxplot with labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2THu.png)

Using the same data, I am also trying to create a faceted plot based on the protein column, but only the first 3 labels are used.

```
mydata.stat<-boxplot(value~protein+variable, data=mydata, plot=FALSE)
mydata.n<-mydata.stat$n
mydata <- ddply(mydata,.(protein,variable),transform,N=length(protein)) 
mydata$label <- as.character(mydata$N) 
count1 <- mydata.n[1]
count2 <- mydata.n[2]
count3 <- mydata.n[3]
count4 <- mydata.n[4]
count5 <- mydata.n[5]
count6 <- mydata.n[6]
count7 <- mydata.n[7]
count8 <- mydata.n[8]
count9 <- mydata.n[9]
Combined1 <-bquote(atop("Prot1", "(n="*.(count1)*")"))
Combined2 <-bquote(atop("Prot2", "(n="*.(count2)*")"))
Combined3 <-bquote(atop("Prot3", "(n="*.(count3)*")"))
Helix1   <-bquote(atop("Prot1", "(n="*.(count4)*")"))
Helix2  <-bquote(atop("Prot2", "(n="*.(count5)*")"))
Helix3   <-bquote(atop("Prot3", "(n="*.(count6)*")"))
Loop1   <-bquote(atop("Prot1", "(n="*.(count7)*")"))
Loop2   <-bquote(atop("Prot2", "(n="*.(count8)*")"))
Loop3   <-bquote(atop("Prot3", "(n="*.(count9)*")"))
xaxislabs <- c (Combined1, Combined2, Combined3, Helix1, Helix2, Helix3, Loop1, Loop2, Loop3)
p <- ggplot(datacolor, aes(x=protein, y=value, group=(protein))) 
p <- p + geom_boxplot(notch=addnotch, outlier.size=0, fill = NA, col = "black", lwd = 0.5) 
p <- p + facet_grid(.~variable, scales = "free_x")
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(labels=c(xaxislabs))
ggsave(p, file="boxplot-facet.pdf" , device=cairo_pdf, width=8, height=8)
```

Sorry for the long post. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please make your example minimal and reproducible.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your error.  Is the screen version showing the right thing?

Comment: Full code ... we need FULL code. Plotting to a device? Post the CODE.