# parsed labels along one facet axis, unparsed labels along the other

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm trying to find a convenient solution to a scenario where I have multi-line, plain-text labels for one faceting dimension and plotmath-style math expressions for the other faceting dimensions. The various solutions to multi-line strip labels (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198170/combining-expression-with-n)) are a bit clunky for my case; I have factor labels in `snake_case` and want to be able to convert them all to multiline versions programmatically without descending into `substitute(bquote(parse(...))` hell (although solutions along those lines would also be accepted).

The direction I went was to (try to) write a custom labeller that would apply `label_parsed()` or leave the labels alone depending on whether they contained newlines or not.  I can't seem to get quite the right syntax for the parsed stuff.  The current structure of the multi-line, unparsed stuff is

```
List of 1
 $ : chr [1:4] "peak\ntime" "peak\nvirulence" "equilibrium\nvirulence" "relative\npeak"
```

which works, but the parsed stuff is

```
List of 3
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ :  expression(beta)
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ :  expression(gamma)
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ :  expression(x[1])
```

which doesn't. Applying `unlist(r)` and `unlist(r,recursive=FALSE)` to this structure both give error messages ...

The result (shown below) is that all three of the parsed labels get stacked up in the first column ...

`?label_parsed` says

> The return value must be a rectangular list where each 'row'
>        characterises a single facet. The list elements can be either
>        character vectors or lists of plotmath expressions. When multiple
>        elements are returned, they get displayed on their own new lines
>        (i.e., each facet gets a multi-line strip of labels).

Setup: load package, define old and new labels

```
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
orig_sum_labs <- c("peak_time","peak_vir","eq_vir","rel_peak")
new_sum_labs <- c("peak time","peak virulence","equilibrium virulence",
                  "relative peak")
fake <- data.frame(f1=rep(orig_sum_labs,each=12),
                   f2=factor(rep(1:3,16),levels=1:3,
                             labels=c("beta","gamma","x[1]")),
                   x=rep(1:4,12),y=rep(1:4,12))
```

Put newlines into labels:

```
nn <- gsub(" ","\n",new_sum_labs)
fake$f1 <- factor(fake$f1,levels=orig_sum_labs,labels=nn)
```

My labeller function:

```
L <- function(labels,multi_line=TRUE) {
    r <- if (all(grepl("\n",labels[[1]]))) {
        list(as.character(labels[[1]]))
    } else {
        label_parsed(labels[[1]],multi_line=multi_line)
    }
    ## browser()
    return(r)
}
class(L) <- "labeller"
```

Try it out:

```
ggplot(fake,aes(x,y))+geom_point()+
    facet_grid(f1~f2,labeller=L)
```

[image]

Comment: I solved this (see below); if it seems not-useful I can delete it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops.  It's a bit magical (and I would happily accept answers that **explain clearly what's going on**), but I managed to solve my problem. In my labeller function above,

```
label_parsed(labels[[1]],multi_line=multi_line)
```

doesn't work, but

```
label_parsed(labels,multi_line=multi_line)
```

works ...

[image]