# Multiline `expression()` in ggplot2 title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198170/combining-expression-with-n) and this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223846/ggplot2-two-line-label-with-expression) bout using `\n` and `expression` in `ggplot2` axis labels but it seems it does not work for title (or for multi line expressions).

My original plot follows:

```
ggplot(data = fig3, aes(x=crude_beta_time6, y=vidD_beta_time6)) + 
    geom_point(shape=18, size=5, color="gray60") + xlab("Coefficients of the crude model") + 
    ylab(bquote("Coefficients of the total 25(OH)D"[3]~"adjusted model")) + 
    theme_bw(base_size = 17) + theme(
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray20", size = 0.3, linetype = "dashed"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "gray40", size = 0.3, linetype = "dashed")
    ) + ggtitle(expression(paste("(B) Coefficients of the crude model vs the total 25(OH)", D[3]," adjusted model (0h vs 6h)", sep="")))
```

[image]

But the title is too long so I tried to place two break-lines using the `atop` command recommended in the cited question: one between *vs* and *the* and the second between *model* and *(0h vs 6h)*.

```
ggplot(data = fig3, aes(x=crude_beta_time6, y=vidD_beta_time6)) + 
    geom_point(shape=18, size=5, color="gray60") + xlab("Coefficients of the crude model") + 
    ylab(bquote("Coefficients of the total 25(OH)D"[3]~"adjusted model")) + 
    theme_bw(base_size = 17) + theme(
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray20", size = 0.3, linetype = "dashed"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "gray40", size = 0.3, linetype = "dashed")
    ) + ggtitle(expression(atop(paste("(B) Coefficients of the crude model vs\nthe total 25(OH)", D[3]," adjusted model\n(0h vs 6h)", sep=""))))
```

And I get this strange behaviour of the title:

[image]

How can I get a three line and centred title thought an expression?

**UPDATE**:

User *Shirin Glander* suggested to update the margins of the plot in order to make more space for the title. Follows the provided code:

```
ggplot(data = fig3, aes(x=crude_beta_time6, y=vidD_beta_time6)) + 
geom_point(shape=18, size=5, color="gray60") + xlab("Coefficients of the crude model") + 
ylab(bquote("Coefficients of the total 25(OH)D"[3]~"adjusted model")) + 
theme_bw(base_size = 17) + theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray20", size = 0.3, linetype = "dashed"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "gray40", size = 0.3, linetype = "dashed")) + 
ggtitle(expression(atop(paste("(B) Coefficients of the crude model vs\nthe total 25(OH)", D[3]," adjusted model\n(0h vs 6h)", sep="")))) + 
theme(plot.margin=unit(c(4,0,0,0),"cm"))
```

The results of this code adds more space for the title, but the titles is not property shown:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the upper margins. Then also, expression does not play well with line breaks. Try this:

```
ggplot(data = fig3, aes(x=crude_beta_time6, y=vidD_beta_time6)) + 
geom_point(shape=18, size=5, color="gray60") + xlab("Coefficients of the crude model") + 
ylab(bquote("Coefficients of the total 25(OH)D"[3]~"adjusted model")) + 
theme_bw(base_size = 17) + theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray20", size = 0.3, linetype = "dashed"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "gray40", size = 0.3, linetype = "dashed")
) + ggtitle(expression(atop("(B) Coefficients of the crude model vs", "the total 25(OH)" ~ D[3] ~ "adjusted model (0h vs 6h)"))) + 
theme(plot.margin=unit(c(4,0,0,0),"cm"))
```

I simply added `theme(plot.margin=unit(c(4,0,0,0),"cm"))` and removed the paste command inside `expression()`. You can set new lines in expression by `","`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, for me it doesn't worked. I updated the questions with another picture of the obtained results. While the margins are, more or less, properly set, the titles is not properly displayed.