# how to add symbols or signs like ≤ or ≠ to a legend or axis in R

Tags: r, plotmath

I want to add the symbol **≤** in to a legend in R as in

```
..."≤1",col="gray"...
```

but when I run the script it creates and = symbol as if I have typed

```
..."=1",col="gray"...
```

Is there a way I can tell R I want that ≤ symbol?

*And to help anyone with a similar problem*; is there a list of commands that can be used to tell R how to add unusual characters?

Comment: see [`plotmath`](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html), In this case  `%<=% 1,col="grey"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192984

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @agstudy for pointing me in the right direction, took a little tweaking but got there with this:

```
   legend(...expression(""<="1.0"),col="gray"...)
```

More symbols can be found in the using `?plotmath` ([see here](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html)) and are implemented using `expression()`

Here is an example:

[image]

```
x <- 0:64/64
y <- sin(3*pi*x)
plot(x, y, type= "l", col= "blue",
     main= expression("How to add the symbol"<="to a legend"))
points(x, y, pch= 1, bg= "white")
legend(.4,1, expression(""<= "1.0"), pch= 1, pt.bg= "white", lty= 1, col= "blue")
```

Comment: @agstudy I can't accept a self answer for two days, if you copy this in to a new answer I'll delete this one and accept & upvote yours

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help finding the solution & adding the example to the answer