# How to display greater than or equal to sign using unicode \u2265

Tags: r, symbols

This is a follow up question to ["Displaying a greater than or equal sign"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192984/displaying-a-greater-than-or-equal-sign)

This is the text I wish to display as the y axis label:
`Pr(Number of Invasions, X ≥ x)`

This is the code:

```
expression(paste("Pr(Number of Invasions,  ", italic('X'), "\u2265", italic('x'), ")"))
```

What I get is:
`Pr(Number of Invasions, X = x)`

This is the same result in the thread mentioned above. `"\u2265"` is supposed to overcome the issue, as suggested in the answers to the thread but it doesn't in my case.

When I run "\u2265" the result is:

```
"\u2265"
[1] "≥"
```

When I assign this to an object I get the same result:

```
symbol<-"\u2265"
symbol
[1] "≥"
```

However, in the Global Environment the object "symbol" contains "=".

Can anyone suggest how to display the symbol in the plot?
The answer isn't obvious to me.

I'm using RStudio, and OS system is Windows 7

Comment: Can you add your OS please ... symbol renders using ubuntu14.04

Comment: OS system is Windows 7.

Comment: What does "Global Environment the object 'symbol' contains '='" mean exactly? Is the 'symbol' you are showing us not in the global environment? And what does that variable have to do with the plotmath anyway? A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful here.

Comment: And does `plot(1,1, main=expression("Pr"~(list("Number of Invasions",X>=x))))` work for you?

Comment: Yes, that displays the symbol. I think I see the problem. The issue is I'm formatting the Xs as italic so that expression doesn't evaluate >= properly.

Comment: I've you've solved your own problem, put it as an answer to close out the question and to help others in the future.

Answer (score 4):

By placing quotations marks around >= or \u2265 within paste within expression, it is was not able to produce the right symbol.
Even though I was formatting the Xs in italics, I should have just treated the code as if it was X>=x, which is what expression really wants to see, as MrFlick suggested... which makes sense now.
So:

> expression(paste("Pr(Number of Invasions", italic('X')>=italic('x'), ")"))

Thanks MrFick!

Comment: It is simply untrue that you cannot get `'\u2265'` to produce a .GE. symbol inside a plotmath paste expression (at least assuming the unicode value maps to that character in your installed font). Use: `expression(paste(italic(X),'\u2265',italic(x) ) `

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `paste`. It's often clearer to use `~` and `*` as separators

```
plot(1,1, xlab=expression(Pr*'('*Number~of~Invasions~~ italic(X)*'\u2265'*italic(x)*")")  )
```

That way it's easier to transition to the "full" plotmath version which gets a different spacing and looks better:

```
plot(1,1,
      xlab=expression( Pr*'('*Number~of~Invasions~~ italic(X) >= italic(x)*")" )
     )
```

If you had really wanted to have a named token hold the  "≥"  character, you can use the `bquote` and `.( )`-functions. The names inside the `.( )` get evaluated (when the dot-function is within bquote):

```
symbol<-"\u2265"
plot(1,1,xlab=bquote(Pr*'('*Number~of~Invasions~~ italic(X) * .(symbol) * italic(x)*")") )
```