# Facet labels involving a greek symbol

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have the data and plot as follows:

```
mydata = data.frame(x=rnorm(4), y=runif(4), tau=c(0,0,1,1))
ggplot(mydata) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + facet_wrap(~ tau)
```

I would like the facet labels to read "tau=0" and "tau=1", respectively, with tau formatted as its greek symbol. I know from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2) that using the labeller `label_parsed` will format the letter tau by itself, but the equal sign seems to complicate things. An ideal solution would not require me to change the data (i.e. make tau a factor and name its levels), but I will take whatever works :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

here a solution with `facet_grid` adn indexing the tau by its levels.

```
mydata = data.frame(x=rnorm(4), y=runif(4), tau=c(0,0,1,1))
ggplot(mydata) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
         facet_grid(~ tau,labeller = label_bquote(tau ^ .(x)))
```

[image]

**Edit** To get the  "tau=0" and "tau=1"

```
facet_grid(~ tau,labeller = label_bquote(tau == .(x)))
```

**Edit2** second variable sigma

I find this solution, by defining a custom labeller. Hope someone ( ggplot2 guys ) give me a simpler solution.

[image]

```
my.label_bquote <- function (expr1 = (tau == .(x)),expr2 = (sigma == .(x))) 
{
   quoted1<- substitute(expr1)
   quoted2 <- substitute(expr2)
   function(variable, value) {
      value <- as.character(value)
      if(variable == 'tau')
         lapply(value, function(x)
               eval(substitute(bquote(expr1, list(x = x)),list(expr1 = quoted1))))
      else
         lapply(value, function(x) 
               eval(substitute(bquote(expr2, list(x = x)),list(expr2 = quoted2))))
   }
}

mydata = data.frame(x=rnorm(4), y=runif(4), tau=c(0,0,1,1),sigma=c(2,2,3,3))
ggplot(mydata) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  facet_grid(sigma ~ tau,labeller = my.label_bquote())
```

Comment: Nice! Can this also be extended to two dimensions? E.g. if I have a second variable sigma I want to facet on, using `facet_grid`.

Comment: The second variable solution is very "single use" but it worked for me after a little modification. In particular, I removed the parentheses around values to `expr1` and `expr2` and commented out the `browser()` call. Also the `variable == 'tau'` had to be changed for my application.

Comment: @ZoëClark Thank you for you feedback. I removed the browser statement.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier solution to this. The simulated data variable names have been changed for clarity in how they work within the labeller argument.

```
mydata = data.frame(x=rnorm(4), y=runif(4), tauvar=c(0,0,1,1),sigmavar=c(2,2,3,3))

ggplot(mydata) + 
   geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
   facet_grid(sigmavar ~ tauvar,labeller = label_bquote(sigma==.(sigmavar),
                                                   tau==.(tauvar)))
```