# R Greek letters and normal letters for facet label in R facet grid

Tags: r, label

I would like to change the facet labels, such that I have greek letters on the y axis and normal text on the x axis. The testing data is:

```
testdata<-data.frame(Method2=c("a","a","b","b"),
 gamma=c(0,1,0,1),values=c(1,2,3,4),x=rep(1,4),y=rep(1,4))

testplot2<-ggplot(data=testdata,aes(x=Method2,y=gamma))
testplot2<-testplot2+facet_grid(gamma~Method2 )
testplot2+geom_point()
```

So far I have tried the following in many differnt constellations and I'm getting rather desperate:
1) To change the names in the data frame with the paste expression and I used label_parsed without much success.

```
gamma<- factor(sapply(testdata$gamma, function(n){
 if(n %in% c("0")) paste(expression(gamma),"0") else
 if(n %in% c("1")) paste(expression(gamma),"1") 
}), levels=c(paste(expression(gamma),"0"),
         paste(expression(gamma),"1")
))
testdata$gamma <- gamma
```

2) And I have tried to use a labeller with

```
my.label_bquote <- function (expr1 = (gamma == .(x)),expr2 = x) 
 {
     quoted1<- substitute(expr1)

    function(variable, value) {
         value <- as.character(value)
         browser()
         if(variable == gamma)
             lapply(value, function(x) eval(substitute(bquote(expr1, list(x = x)),list(expr1 = quoted1))))

        else if(variable == Method2){

           value[value=="a"]   <- "Whatever"
           value[value=="b"]   <- "Whatever2"

         }
         return(value)

         }
 }
```

which is a changed form of a previous answer given to a similar question:
[Facet labels involving a greek symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181234/facet-labels-involving-a-greek-symbol)

Would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about we create a label swapper factory of sorts. Here's a generic function that will allow for renaming of levels of values in facet labels

```
get_label_swap <- function(...) {
    dots<-list(...)
    function(variable, value) {
        if(variable %in% names(dots)) {
            swaps <- dots[[variable]]
            vals <- as.character(value)
            lapply(vals, function(v) {if(v %in% names(swaps)) swaps[[v]] else v })
        } else {
            label_value(variable, value)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to get one specific to your problem, we would do

```
label_swap <- get_label_swap(gamma=list("0"=expression(gamma*0), 
                                        "1"=expression(gamma*1)))
```

So the function looks at the named parameters and expects a list where the names of the list are the values of the factor, and the values in the list are what you want to replace them with. So only for the variable "gamma" will it swap "0" and "1" with the appropriate expressions. Then it returns a function we can pass as a `labeller=` parameter to ggplot. Thus we plot with

```
testplot2 <- ggplot(data=testdata,aes(x=Method2,y=gamma))
testplot2 <- testplot2+facet_grid(gamma~Method2, labeller=label_swap)
testplot2 + geom_point()
```

which results in

[image]

The newest version of ggplot no longer supports these types of labellers, here's a possible alternative solution using the new `labeller_bquote` function

```
ggplot(data=testdata,aes(x=Method2,y=gamma)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(gamma~Method2, labeller=label_bquote(rows=gamma*.(gamma)))
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much! I had a bit of a fuss with getting the expression right, as I wanted "gamma=1", which has been another problem, which I had in the first example. So if anybody is interested in this

Comment: If you want `gamma=0/1` in the facet label, just use `get_label_swap(gamma=list("0"=expression(gamma==0), "1"=expression(gamma==1)))`

Comment: Sorry I could not finish my comment and you were faster. I circumvented the problem with writing "expression(gamma*"=0.001")". Anyway thank you so much, this is fantastic! :) You made my day.

Comment: Doesn't work with ggplot2 version  3.3.2, but was close. So I would appreciate if anyone could produce an update on this great solution.

Comment: @ClemSnide Things have changed a lot I guess. I updated with a new solution using `label_bquote` that works for this particular case but it's a different approach.