# How can I have a Greek symbol within one of my facet labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-wrap

I'm trying to create a plot using ggplot2 (v. 2_2.2.1) `facet_wrap`, and I need to have a Greek symbol in only one facet label (out of five). I have tried to use code posted here on Stack Overflow:

- [R Greek letters and normal letters for facet label in R facet grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579804/r-greek-letters-and-normal-letters-for-facet-label-in-r-facet-grid)
- [How to add expressions to labels in facet_wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282897/how-to-add-expressions-to-labels-in-facet-wrap)
- [How can I use grid to edit a ggplot2 object to add math expressions to facet labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525857/how-can-i-use-grid-to-edit-a-ggplot2-object-to-add-math-expressions-to-facet-lab)

but without any success (getGrob is not working, and that's true also for the mf_labeller).

Can anyone help me with that?

Here is the example code:

```
df <- data.frame(genes = rep(c("BA","MLL","pos","neg","PMLalpha+"),5), value = sample(1:100, 25, replace=TRUE))
df$genes <- factor(df$genes, levels = c("BA","MLL","pos","neg","PMLalpha+"), ordered = TRUE)
ggplot(df,aes(x=genes, y=value)) + geom_boxplot()+ 
  facet_wrap(~genes, ncol = 5,scales = "free_x")+
  scale_x_discrete(name="",
               breaks = c("BA","MLL","pos","neg","PMLalpha+"),
               labels = c("BA","MLL","pos","neg",expression(paste("PML", alpha,"+"))))
```

I'm able to rename the x-axis tick, but I just can't do that within the facet labels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a trick that uses `labeller=label_parsed`.

First, define labels for `df$genes` that uses the expression to be parsed:

```
df$genes <- factor(df$genes, levels = c("BA","MLL","pos","neg","PMLalpha+"),
 ordered = TRUE, labels=c("BA","MLL","pos","neg",expression(paste("PML", alpha,"+"))))
```

Then use `labeller=label_parsed` in `facet_wrap`:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=genes, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~genes, ncol = 5, scales = "free_x", labeller = label_parsed)
```

As you can see this messes with the x-axis labels, but you can fix it in `scale_x_discrete` as follows:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=genes, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~genes, ncol = 5, scales = "free_x", labeller = label_parsed) +
  scale_x_discrete(name="",
               breaks = c("BA","MLL","pos","neg","paste(\"PML\", alpha, \"+\")"),
               labels = c("BA","MLL","pos","neg", expression(paste("PML", alpha,"+"))))
```

[image]

**Edit:** In response to follow-up question posted, here is the solution for using `label_parsed` for more than one variable. Includes requested space in the variable strings.

```
df$var2 <- c(rep(c('trt a','trt b'), NROW(df)/2),'trt a')
df$var2 <- factor(df$var2, levels=c('trt a','trt b'), ordered=T, labels=c(expression(paste("trt ", alpha)), expression(paste("trt ", beta))))
```

ggplot(df,aes(x=var2, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() +
facet_wrap(~var2, ncol = 5, scales = "free_x", labeller = label_parsed)

Fix the x-axis:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=var2, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~var2, ncol = 5, scales = "free_x", labeller = label_parsed) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name="",
                 breaks = c(expression(paste("trt ", alpha)), expression(paste("trt ", beta))),
                 labels = c(expression(paste("trt ", alpha)), expression(paste("trt ", beta))))
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to only use `label_parsed` for more than one variable? For example add another variable to `df` that is a character string with a space (the space is important). `df$var2 <- c(rep(c('trt a','trt b'),NROW(df)/2),'trt a')`. Now run the plot code and you get the error: `Error in parse(text = as.character(values)) :  <text>:1:5: unexpected symbol
1: trt a ^` because it's trying to evaluate this as a math expression. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps a way to ignore the variable with the space?

Comment: Agree above, added solution to above question to the answer above.