# Modify facets label names in ggplot with greek letters and superscripts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below plot, but I'd like to express the isotope names in proper delta format. Previously, I've used the following code for this in an axis label:

```
p + labs(x = expression(paste(paste(delta^2,"H"))))
```

But that doesn't work in the facet_grid labeller for my figure below:

```
p + facet_grid(sex ~ iso,
             scale = "free_x",
             labeller = labeller(iso = c("d2H" = expression(paste(paste(delta^2,"H"))), 
                                         "d13C" = expression(paste(paste(delta^13,"C"))),
                                         "d15N" = expression(paste(paste(delta^15,"N")))),
                                 sex = c("F" = "female",
                                         "M" = "male")))
```

How can I change the names in the facets?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [Greek symbol within tha facet labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971945/greek-symbol-within-tha-facet-labels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `label_parsed` as a `labeller`. But to do that the labels of the faceting factor need to be changed to what is to be displayed.
I will use the built-in dataset `iris` as an example.

```
library(ggplot2)

iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species, 
                       labels = c(bquote(delta^2*H),
                                  bquote(delta^13*C),
                                  bquote(delta^15*N)))

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point()

p + facet_grid(~ Species,
               scale = "free_x",
               labeller = label_parsed
               )
```

[image]