# Greek letters in ggplot annotate

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add greek letters into text in ggplot. Here is what I want to do:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x =  rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
xIntercept <- mean(df$x)
yIntercept <- mean(df$y)
temp <- paste("theta = ", xIntercept) # This Works
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() +
  annotate("text", x = xIntercept, y = yIntercept, label = temp, color = "blue")
```

Instead of "theta", I want to use Greek letter theta. I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2) but cannot do it. I tried following codes but nothing happened:

```
temp <- list(bquote(theta == .(xIntercept)))
temp <- bquote(theta == .(xIntercept))
temp <- expression(theta, "=", xIntercept)
temp <- c(expression(theta), paste0("=", xIntercept))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your link states that in `annotate` you should use `parse = TRUE`. So

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() +
  annotate("text", x = xIntercept, y = yIntercept, label = temp, color = "blue", parse = TRUE)
```

works and gives a greek theta symbol. 
EDIT: However the `=` sign is parsed too, so as [MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick) noted you should go for

```
temp <- paste("theta == ", xIntercept)
```

Comment: `temp <- paste("theta == ", xIntercept)` would keep the equals sign.