# Axis label with absolute value bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I would like to create a plot in ggplot2, where the xaxis is |r|, meaning the absolute value of r. Based on [How to use Greek symbols in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2) I've found that I can use the following to get the greek symbol beta, but how I do get the absolute value bars?

`p <- p + xlab(expression(beta))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `paste` inside `expression` to add in the pipes, `|`.

```
xlab(expression(paste("|", beta, "|")))
```

Which would look something like:
[image]

**Edit** to show how to change fonts

If you're not using greek letters, you don't necessarily need `expression`.  You can control the `family` and `face` of the letters via `element_text` in `theme.  You just need to figure out what you are going for.

Here's one way to change the family and font:

```
xlab("| r |") + 
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family = "serif", face = "italic"))
```

To do the same thing using `expression`:

```
xlab(expression(italic("| r |"))) + 
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family = "serif"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm not using it for a greek letter, but for a normal letter. Is there a way to make it look more math-like? For instance, like the label in this plot: http://imgur.com/5vGZ8MW

Comment: @felbo Maybe you want italics and/or a different font?  You could try playing around with fonts a la `+ theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family = "serif"))`.  You can do italics inside expressions, as well - try just `italic("| r |")` in `expression`.