# Using the R sub() function to replace a letter with a Greek letter

Tags: r, unicode, ggplot2

I am trying to use the undercase omega symbol in my R `ggplot2` figure legend. I have attempted to use the function `sub()` to substitute the `"w"` in my data with the unicode character for undercase omega. However, when I print the vector or data frame  w is replaced with `"Ï‰"`.

**Example code:**

```
taxa <- c('16w.1', '18w.2.3w6', '15')
count<- c(21, 23, 27)
microbe.data <- data.frame(taxa, count)
my_labels <- sub(pattern = "w", replacement = "\U03C9", x = microbe.data$taxa)
```

**my outcome:**

```
"16Ï‰.1"     "18Ï‰.2.3w6" "15"
```

Has anyone else run into this issue, any advice?

Comment: Take a look at the links next to your question. There are a lot of them asking about greek letters in `ggplot2` figures.

Comment: Here's one that might help on Greek letters in `ggplot`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5294214/8382207

Comment: What version of R are you running and what is the output from `Sys.getlocale()`? (When I run your code I get lowercase omegas.)

Comment: Try setting `Encoding(my_labels) <- "UTF-8"`. I'm guessing you are on windows with UTF-8 encoding is not the default.

Comment: @MrFlick I'm on Windows and your tip solved it.

Comment: Thank you MrFlick this was it!

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Thanks Imo, I have learned a lot from the links when I was searching for help but couldn't directly answer my question. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Thank you joran, I had tried re-installing R and rstudio a few days ago, just to be safe.