# How to make subscripts in axis text in ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data code is:

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("NO", "H2O2"),
  values = c(10,11)
)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=group, y=values))+ geom_col(width = 0.5)+
  theme_bw()
```

This plots a graph, like this:[image]

I want both '2' in H2O2 as subscripts. How can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to subscript the x axis tick label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978011/how-to-subscript-the-x-axis-tick-label)

Comment: yes. It has answered my question. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the example code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50058590/add-latex-expression-on-x-axis-ticks-ggplot2)

In your case...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("NO", "H2O2"),
  values = c(10,11)
)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=group, y=values))+ geom_col(width = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("NO", "H2O2"),
                   labels = c("NO", parse(text=TeX("$H_2O_2$")))
                   ) +
  theme_bw()
```