# When using the units package, how can I get the unit labels on the axes to render as Greek letters?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, units-of-measurement

The units package in R is very useful in dealing with unit conversions and can be used for plotting in base plot and using the ggplot + ggforce combo. However, in the current form, units that should include Greek letters are not typeset correctly. Is there a way to have Greek letters in units displayed on the graph using the units package?

```
library(units)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

df = cars
df$Distance = set_units(df$dist, ft)/1000
df$Speed = set_units(df$speed, mph)

qplot(x=Speed, y=Distance, data=df) +
  scale_y_unit(unit = "um") 
# The Y-axis labels uses the latin u instead of the Greek mu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now possible to insert Greek letters directly into R code which should allow one to have Greek letters on the axes.

```
qplot(x=Speed, y=Distance, data=df) +
  scale_y_unit(unit = "μm")
```

This did not work for me with R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) (see error message below). In this case, upgrade your R installation.

```
Error: In ‘µm’, ‘µm’ is not recognized by udunits.
See a table of valid unit symbols and names with valid_udunits().
Add custom user-defined units with install_symbolic_unit().
```

Credits to Edzer Pebesma for finding the solution (see https://github.com/r-quantities/units/issues/238)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2?answertab=active#tab-top) shows how to use greek letters in ggplot. `mu` can be added to the y axis label by using `expression`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=Speed, y=Distance)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_unit(name = expression(paste("Distance [", mu, "m]")), unit = "um")
```

However, the origin text `[um]` in the label can not be removed. `scale_*_unit` add `[<unit>]` to the axis label by default.

Comment: So it seems that the answer to the question is "no". I've filed an issue on the GitHub page: https://github.com/r-quantities/units/issues/238

Comment: IMP,  this is caused by `scale_y_unit()` in ggforce package

Comment: I agree that this could probably be fixed through ggforce, but the behavior is the same in base plot.