# Mathematical (set) symbol in ggplot axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, symbols

I am trying to include mathematical signs into `ggplot` axis labels. Consider the following code.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"), len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=1)) +
  ylab("length")+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()
```

I would now like to include the range of `len ("Length")` in the y axis description with the notation `Length ∈ [0, 10]` but can't find a way to get the "element of" sign into the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a great post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2) that goes through the different ways, here I use `expression`

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=1)) +
  ylab("length")+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() +
  ylab(expression("Length " ~ epsilon ~ " [0, 10]"))
```

EDIT:
Since the symbol for element of is `\in`, the expression code does not work since `in` is a built-in function. There are likely workaround, but I had to resort to using the `latex2exp` package

```
library(latex2exp)


ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=1)) +
  ylab("length")+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() +
  ylab(TeX(sprintf("Length $\\in$ \\[0, 10\\]")))
```

Comment: Interesting work around.  Similarly, using `"\U03F5"` gives you an epsilon.  Unfortunately, it's not quite the same as the "element of" unicode character OP was requesting.

Comment: typo on symbol to use, thanks for pointing out. 

Latex symbol is `\in` which is built in and leads to issues, seems like the only symbol that won't work w this method. I think it's useful to share still

Comment: This, too only gives me the square - is this an issue with my system - and how could I address this?

Answer (score 0):

For special symbols, you can reference their Unicode value via the escape character `\U####`.  ∈ is Unicode (U+2208), so using `\U2208` can be used to paste the ∈ symbol.

So:

```
> 'Length \U2208 [0, 10]'
[1] "Length ∈ [0, 10]"
```

And then you can just use `ylab('Length \U2208 [0, 10]')` in your plot code.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to address the issue of the symbol not showing - but instead the square typical for encoding errors?

Comment: Doesn't look like that character is supported in ggplot from what I can see.  I've tried a few things, but have not found a good way to address - I'm able to get the output in the console, but not on a plot.

Comment: yes, the same happens to me - the console works fine but not with `ggplot`. Is there something to be done?

Comment: I've gone the route of trying to adjust the font (see `extrafonts` package), but no luck so far.  It also does not seem to matter if I export via png (graphics device) or pdf (cairo_pdf or standard).  It also does not print correctly using `annotate()` or `annotate_custom()`, which leads me to find that the issue is not related at all to how the functions create the plot, but how the plot is realized via the graphics device in R.  The only workaround would be to create an image file with the character and use a custom annotation to place that outside the plot.