# Replace legend labels/texts with Greek (i.e. LaTeX) symbols

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, latex

I am trying to create a plot containing two lines with different shapes and colour.

I have checked a number of similar questions online but I have not been successful.   I have been able to do the following so far

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
v1 <-c(0.000120,-0.000085,-0.000018,0.000005)
v2 <- c(0.000164,0.000041,-0.000032,0.000031)
v3 <- c(500,1000,5000,10000)
dfr <- data.frame(rate1=v1,rate2=v2,quantity=v3)
dfr <- melt(dfr,id='quantity',value.name="res")
ggplot(dfr, aes(x=quantity, y=res,group=variable,shape=variable)) +
  geom_line(size=1, aes(linetype=variable,colour=variable)) + 
  geom_point( size=4,aes(colour=variable))+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.0001,0.0002)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(500,1000,5000,10000))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "longdash"))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype="dotted",size=1)
```

[image: First plot]

However, I want to do the following:

1. Replace the legend texts/labels: **rate1** and **rate2** with two Greek **lambda** symbols.
2. Finally, hide the legend title **variable**.

When I try to include this: `scale_colour_manual( values=c('#F8766D','#00BFC4'),labels = unname(TeX(c(" $\\lambda_1$", "$\\lambda_2$"))))`, so as to change the legend text, I get an extra legend below:

[image: second plot with extra legend]

Please how can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that by changing the labels in `scale_linetype` but not for the other scales (`color` and `shape`) `ggplot2` will no longer merge them into one legend. Hence you have the change the labels for the other scales as well. However, using `Tex()` I did not manage to make this work. But following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2) using `bquote` worked fine. Finally, to get rid of the legend title simply use `labs()` to set the title for all three scales to `NULL`

**EDIT** Thanks to @mischva for checking and pointing out that using `labels <- unname(TeX(c(" $\\lambda_1$", "$\\lambda_2$")))` will also work fine. Interestingly it does not work if one puts it directly into the three scales functions. That's what I tried.

```r
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
v1 <-c(0.000120,-0.000085,-0.000018,0.000005)
v2 <- c(0.000164,0.000041,-0.000032,0.000031)
v3 <- c(500,1000,5000,10000)
dfr <- data.frame(rate1=v1,rate2=v2,quantity=v3)
dfr <- melt(dfr,id='quantity',value.name="res")

labels <- c(bquote(lambda[1]), bquote(lambda[2]))

ggplot(dfr, aes(x=quantity, y=res,group=variable,shape=variable)) +
  geom_line(size=1, aes(linetype=variable,colour=variable)) + 
  geom_point( size=4,aes(colour=variable))+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.0001,0.0002)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(500,1000,5000,10000))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "longdash"), labels = labels)+
  scale_shape_discrete(labels = labels)+
  scale_colour_discrete(labels = labels) +
  labs(color = NULL, linetype = NULL, shape = NULL) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype="dotted",size=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I was on the same track, but you were faster. You can change your `labels` to `labels <- unname(TeX(c(" $\\lambda_1$", "$\\lambda_2$")))`, then it will work like OP suggested with any `LaTex` code through `latex2exp`.

Comment: @stefan thanks a lot, problem solved!  I learnt quite a few new things from your explanation.

Comment: @mischva11 thanks for your contribution. `labels <- unname(TeX(c(" $\\lambda_1$", "$\\lambda_2$")))` also works just fine too.