# How to pass an expression to a geom_text label in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, subscript, geom-text

I am attempting to pass an expression with subscript to a single `geom_text()` label in `ggplot`. Here is my code right now:

```
my_exp <- expression('my_exp'[s][u][b])

my_data <- 
  data.frame(
    var_1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
    var_2 = c(1, 2, 3)
  )

my_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = var_1, y = var_2))+
  geom_text(aes(label = var_1))
```

Here is the resulting plot:

[image: [Here is the resulting plot][1].]

What I would like to do is replace the `var_1` value of `"a"` with the expression specified by `my_exp` and then have `geom_text()` evaluate that value as an expression, resulting in the subscript appearing on the ggplot.

Comment: Some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5293715/5325862) might help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest this approach. You can build another variable for your labels and then enable the option `parse=T` from `geom_text()` in order to have the desired plot. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
#Data
my_exp <- as.character(expression('my_exp'[s][u][b]))

my_data <- 
  data.frame(
    var_1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
    var_2 = c(1, 2, 3),stringsAsFactors = F
  )
#Mutate
my_data$label <- ifelse(my_data$var_1=='a',my_exp,my_data$var_1)
#Plot
my_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = var_1, y = var_2))+
  geom_text(aes(label = label),parse = T)
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:** If there are issues with labels here a code for that:

```
#Label
my_exp <- "14~M~my_exp[s][u][b]"
#Code
my_data <- 
  data.frame(
    var_1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
    var_2 = c(1, 2, 3),stringsAsFactors = F
  )
#Mutate
my_data$label <- ifelse(my_data$var_1=='a',my_exp,my_data$var_1)
#Plot
my_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = var_1, y = var_2))+
  geom_text(aes(label = label),parse = T)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please tell me what happened!

Comment: @RebGray Hi. Are all the labels in character format??

Comment: @RebGray Hi Reb. I have added an update that uses numbers as you said in comments. Please check and let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: Hi - I posted a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815731/how-to-pass-an-expression-to-a-geom-text-label-in-ggplot-continued) as I realized posting code in the comments is probably not good practice. I'll also look for your update - thanks!