# Adding greek symbols to legend ggplot (more than one)

Tags: r, ggplot2

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2) thread has lead me to this nice [wiki](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/Plotmath) on adding greek symbols in `ggplot`. The code below gives alpha and beta a value in the legend. What do I have to do if I want to add more than one greek symbol for the same data point in the legend? For example "alpha =1, gamma = 2"?

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,f=rep(c("alpha","beta"),each=5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

value <- 3.1415
my.labs <- list(bquote(alpha==.(value)),bquote(beta==.(value)))

qplot(x,y,data=d,colour=f) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=1:2,breaks=c("alpha","beta"),
                      labels=my.labs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this. You can smartly use `paste()` to concatenate the elements and add the `,` using `expression()` function:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
d <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,f=rep(c("alpha","beta"),each=5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
value <- 3.1415
my.labs <- c(expression(paste(alpha==1,',',~gamma==2)),expression(beta))
#Plot
qplot(x,y,data=d,colour=f) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=1:2,breaks=c("alpha","beta"),
                      labels=my.labs)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Interesting (+1) but lacks a comma or separator I think

Answer (score 3):

You could just pass them directly as strings using unicode escapes

```r
my.labs <- c("\u03b1 = 1, \u03b3 = 1", paste("\u03b2 =", value))

qplot(x,y,data=d,colour=f) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=1:2, breaks=c("alpha","beta"),
                      labels=my.labs)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! However how do you know the string codes for the symbols?

Comment: @tomka Google "unicode alpha" and use the hexadecimal in front of a `\u` - the Greek letters are all sequential