# Latex and variables in plot label in R?

Tags: r, latex, plot

How do I use variables in Latex expressions in R?

For example:

```
plot(X, Y, main=expression(R^2))
```

Will put R with a nice superscripted 2 as main title.

But let's say I want it to say 'R^2: 0.5', with 0.5 coming from a R variable. How do I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The hack of Owen is pretty cool, but not really the common way to do that. If you use `bquote`, this is actually pretty easy. `bquote` will do the same as `quote`, with the exception that everything between `.()` will be evaluated in a specified environment (or the global, if nothing is specified).

A trivial example :

```
X <- 1:10
Y <- 1:10
a <- 0.8
plot(X,Y,main=bquote(R^2 : .(a)))
```

Gives :

[image]

See also `?bquote` and `?plotmath` for more examples and possibilities

Comment: Nice! I've often wanted something like bquote() but never knew it existed.

Comment: Yup that worked just nice. Weird though it's such a hassle to mix latex and r variables.

Comment: @c00kiemonster R isn't and never was meant as a LaTeX processor. R's `plotmath` functionality has to work within the confines of R syntax and conventions of the parser. Once you get used to it, it is a lot easier than it seems.

Answer (score 3):

Well this works...

```
call(':', quote(R^2), a)
```

though it feels a little hacky to me since it's using R's : operator, whereas you just want to stick some text on the end. Maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 3):

tikz and psfrag allow you to use actual LaTeX code and output instead of plotmath's, resulting in better typographic consistency.

See this question for details. [Getting LaTeX into R Plots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1395105/210673)

Answer (score 2):

Another variation on @Joris' theme is `substitute()`. You give `substitute()` an expression and an environment or list within which to evaluate the expression. Passing a list is usually easiest, especially for jobs such as the one posed here.

```
plot(X,Y, main = substitute(R^2 : a, list(a = a)))
```

We can see why this works, by looking solely at the `substitute()` call:

```
> substitute(R^2 : a, list(a = a))
R^2:0.8
```

The `a` in the expression is replace with the value of `a` in the list.