# Labelling logarithmic scale display in R

Tags: r, label, plot, logarithm, axes

While plotting histogarm, scatterplots and other plots with axes scaled to logarithmic scale in R, how is it possible to use labels such as 10^-1 10^0 10^1 10^2 10^3 and so on instead of the axes showing just -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. What parameters should be added to the commands such as hist(), plot() etc?

Comment: ggplot2 does this automatically if you do the log transformation within ggplot2.  See the examples towards the bottom of this page: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_boxplot.html

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out. Also, I found something very useful here as well http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/log-y-axis-of-histogram-td2399498.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Apart from the solution of ggplot2 (see gsk3's comment), I would like to add that this happens automatically in plot() as well when using the correct arguments, eg :

```
x <- 1:10
y <- exp(1:10)
plot(x,y,log="y")
```

You can use the parameter `log="x"` for the X axis, or `log="xy"` for both.

If you want to format the numbers, or you have the data in log format, you can do a workaround using axis(). Some interesting functions :

- `axTicks(x)` gives you the location of the ticks on the X-axis (x=1) or Y-axis (x=2)
- `bquote()` converts expressions to language, but can replace a variable with its value. More information on `bquote()` in the question [Latex and variables in plot label in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856447/latex-and-variables-in-plot-label-in-r/6856842#6856842) .
- `as.expression()` makes the language object coming from `bquote()` an expression. This allows `axis()` to do the formatting as explained in `?plotmath`. It can't do so with language objects.

An example for nice formatting :

```
x <- y <- 1:10
plot(x,y,yaxt="n")
aty <- axTicks(2)
labels <- sapply(aty,function(i)
            as.expression(bquote(10^ .(i)))
          )
axis(2,at=aty,labels=labels)
```

Which gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is quite useful and I think its a general solution. Worked for me just fine

Answer (score 18):

Here is a different way to draw this type of axis:

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(1, 10^4), xlab="x", ylab="y", log="y", yaxt="n")
at.y <- outer(1:9, 10^(0:4))
lab.y <- ifelse(log10(at.y) %% 1 == 0, at.y, NA)
axis(2, at=at.y, labels=lab.y, las=1)
```

[image]

EDIT: This is also solved in `latticeExtra` with [`scale.components`](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/#scale.components&theme=default)

Answer (score 2):

In ggplot2 you just can add a

```
... + 
scale_x_log10() + 
scale_y_log10(limits = c(1e-4,1), breaks=c(1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,0.1,1)) + ...
```

to scale your axis, Label them and add custom breaks.