# Displaying minor logarithmic ticks in x-axis in R

Tags: r, plot, axis, logarithm

I have a normal distribution plot and a histogram plot with x axis in log scale displaying 0, 10^0, 10^1 ... I want to include minor ticks between the major ones. Actually I was able to change the major ticks format from 1, 2, 3 and so on to 10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3 using the solution given to me in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897243/labelling-logarithmic-scale-display-in-r). I used the following code for the major ticks :

```
major.ticks <- axTicks(1)
labels <- sapply(major.ticks,function(i)
            as.expression(bquote(10^ .(i)))
          )
axis(1,at=major.ticks,labels=labels)
```

Can this be edited to just mark the minor ticks without labeling them?

Comment: Or other new ways are most welcome! Thank you.

Comment: I edited your question to include the link to the previous question. That makes the code and the problem a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a function `minor.tick` in the package `Hmisc`, but that one deals poorly with logarithmical scales. I use the following function for getting minor ticks that follow the logarithmical scale. `ax` is the axis you use it on (same as for the function `axis`), `n` is the number of minor ticks (default to 9), `t.ratio` is the ratio between the major and the minor ticks, and with `...` you can pass extra parameters to `axis`

edit : Nice idea in the comments, so I edited my function. There are two extra parameters, `mn` and `mx` for the minimum and the maximum *on the logarithmic scale* (`mn=0` thus means the minimum is 10^0 or 1 !)

The function:

```
minor.ticks.axis <- function(ax,n,t.ratio=0.5,mn,mx,...){

  lims <- par("usr")
  if(ax %in%c(1,3)) lims <- lims[1:2] else lims[3:4]

  major.ticks <- pretty(lims,n=5)
  if(missing(mn)) mn <- min(major.ticks)
  if(missing(mx)) mx <- max(major.ticks)

  major.ticks <- major.ticks[major.ticks >= mn & major.ticks <= mx]

  labels <- sapply(major.ticks,function(i)
            as.expression(bquote(10^ .(i)))
          )
  axis(ax,at=major.ticks,labels=labels,...)

  n <- n+2
  minors <- log10(pretty(10^major.ticks[1:2],n))-major.ticks[1]
  minors <- minors[-c(1,n)]

  minor.ticks = c(outer(minors,major.ticks,`+`))
  minor.ticks <- minor.ticks[minor.ticks > mn & minor.ticks < mx]


  axis(ax,at=minor.ticks,tcl=par("tcl")*t.ratio,labels=FALSE)
}
```

This can be applied as follows :

```
x <- 10^(0:8)
y <- 1:9
plot(log10(x),y,xaxt="n",xlab="x",xlim=c(0,9))
minor.ticks.axis(1,9,mn=0,mx=8)
```

Gives :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work just fine for me but I had to remove the extra 'm' in minor.ticks.axis(2m).  Also, why is that needed. Now that I have the minor tick, Since my scale starts from 10^0 I would not want extra minor ticks before that. How to control that?

Comment: @user744121 I edited my function, nice idea! The extra 'm' was a typo, I edited that one before. For the rest, see the extra explanation.

Comment: Seems great your function but I have a range between 10^-4 yo 10 ^1. How can we change the fuvntion in order to have the ticks in positions lower than mn=0??

Comment: This should be a function in `graphics`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple function to to this:

```
log10.axis <- function(side, at, ...) {
    at.minor <- log10(outer(1:9, 10^(min(at):max(at))))
    lab <- sapply(at, function(i) as.expression(bquote(10^ .(i))))
    axis(side=side, at=at.minor, labels=NA, tcl=par("tcl")*0.5, ...)
    axis(side=side, at=at, labels=lab, ...)
}
```

Here is an example:

```
x <- exp(rnorm(200, 5))
hist(log(x), 20, xaxt="n", xlim=c(0, 8))
log10.axis(1, at=seq(0, 8, 2))
```

Gives:
[image]

Comment: `tcl=par("tcl")*0.5` is a great trick. In my opinion, this is way simpler than modifying the `minor.tick` function

Answer (score 2):

Try `magaxis` in package [magicaxis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magicaxis).

Answer (score 2):

In `ggplot2`, we can use [`annotation_logticks`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotation_logticks.html) together with `scales::trans_breaks` and `scales::trans_format`. Below is an example taken from the link above.

```
    library(ggplot2)

    a <- ggplot(msleep, aes(bodywt, brainwt)) +
      geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) +
      scale_x_log10(
        breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
        labels = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(10^.x))
      ) +
      scale_y_log10(
        breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
        labels = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(10^.x))
      ) +
      theme_bw()

    a + annotation_logticks() # Default: log ticks on bottom and left
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is the `minorAxis` function in the `StratigrapheR` package, that can be used for any kind of minor ticks. It can be used with the `seq_log` function to make logarithmic ticks:

```
library(StratigrapheR)

x <- exp(rnorm(200, 5))
hist(log10(x), 20, xaxt="n", xlim=c(0, 4), xlab = "x", main = "Logarithmic Histogram of x")

ticks <- seq_log(10^0,10^4, divide = T)

lab <- sapply(0:4, function(i) as.expression(bquote(10^ .(i))))

minorAxis(1, at.maj = log10(ticks[[1]]), at.min = log10(ticks[[2]]), labels = lab)
```

Gives: [image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23849771)

Comment: Much better, would be a complete answer if the labels were in the `10^a` format ( with `a` the appropriate exponents.) Upvote, anyway.

Comment: Oh yes: I added that based on @mrbrich answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `""` for the labels of the minor ticks.

Comment: If you're happy with ticks on a linear scale that are the same size as your major ticks, then this would work. Otherwise things are a bit more complex...

Answer (score 0):

There was a small error,

`lims<-lims[3:4]` was missing

```
   minor.ticks.axis <- function(ax,n,t.ratio=0.5,mn,mx,...){

  lims <- par("usr")
  if(ax %in%c(1,3)) lims <- lims[1:2] else lims <- lims[3:4]

  major.ticks <- pretty(lims,n=5)
  if(missing(mn)) mn <- min(major.ticks)
  if(missing(mx)) mx <- max(major.ticks)

  major.ticks <- major.ticks[major.ticks >= mn & major.ticks <= mx]

  labels <- sapply(major.ticks,function(i)
            as.expression(bquote(10^ .(i)))
          )
  axis(ax,at=major.ticks,labels=labels,...)

  n <- n+2
  minors <- log10(pretty(10^major.ticks[1:2],n))-major.ticks[1]
  minors <- minors[-c(1,n)]

  minor.ticks = c(outer(minors,major.ticks,`+`))
  minor.ticks <- minor.ticks[minor.ticks > mn & minor.ticks < mx]


  axis(ax,at=minor.ticks,tcl=par("tcl")*t.ratio,labels=FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The x axis labels in the first plot on this page is in error.
The minor ticks are not properly distributed.