# How to get a reversed, log10 scale in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to make a plot with a reversed, log10 x scale using ggplot2:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=runif(10))
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
```

However, it seems that I can *either* a log10 scale *or* a reversed scale:

```
p + scale_x_reverse() + scale_x_log10()
```

[image: log10 scale, but not reversed]

```
p + scale_x_reverse()
```

[image: reversed scale, but not log10]

I guess this is logical, if a layer can only have one scale. And certainly I could hack it by doing the log transform on the dataframe myself, `df$xLog <- log10(df$x)`
but that solution is a seems contrary to the spirit of ggplot. Is there a way to get this kind of plot without doing data transformations external to the ggplot call?

Comment: I expected this to work as well, but apparently its a bit complicated. There was a [work-around](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ggplot2/reverse$20log$20scale/ggplot2/AfMf9L9y9fc/Qu-FnJLJaagJ) that appears to be broken in the most recent version. If @kohske or someone can't come up with another solution, might make a good feature request.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[See [@user236321's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72506926/892313) for a more modern (post April 2022) answer.]

The link that @joran gave in his comment gives the right idea (build your own transform), but is outdated with regard to the new `scales` package that `ggplot2` uses now.  Looking at `log_trans` and `reverse_trans` in the scales package for guidance and inspiration, a `reverselog_trans` function can be made:

```
library("scales")
reverselog_trans <- function(base = exp(1)) {
    trans <- function(x) -log(x, base)
    inv <- function(x) base^(-x)
    trans_new(paste0("reverselog-", format(base)), trans, inv, 
              log_breaks(base = base), 
              domain = c(1e-100, Inf))
}
```

This can be used simply as:

```
p + scale_x_continuous(trans=reverselog_trans(10))
```

which gives the plot:

[image]

Using a slightly different data set to show that the axis is definitely reversed:

```
DF <- data.frame(x=1:10,  y=1:10)
ggplot(DF, aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(trans=reverselog_trans(10))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that this solution no longer works:
    Error in reverselog_trans(10) : could not find function "trans_new"
Explicitly adding scales::trans_new only results in new errors, the scales function seems to have been updated :(

Comment: @Richard I just checked it and it works, but the `scales` package must be attached to the search path (`library("scales")`). That is not clear in the answer (and may not have been necessary at the time). Updating.

Comment: That easy huh?! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Alternatively use the :: notation to explicitly call functions from the scales package.  ---
```reverselog_trans <- function(base = exp(1)) {
    trans <- function(x) -log(x, base)
    inv <- function(x) base^(-x)
    scales::trans_new(paste0("reverselog-", format(base)), trans, inv, 
              scales::log_breaks(base = base), 
              domain = c(1e-100, Inf))
}```

Comment: NB: the `reverselog_trans` function has appeared in CRAN https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ACSNMineR/index.html (found in ACSNMineR/R/plots.R).

Comment: @flies If that is exported from the package, you should put together an answer using that. It would be a good addition.

Answer (score 13):

[`ggforce`](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/) package has [`trans_reverser()`](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/trans_reverser.html) function for this task.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = 1:100, y = 1:100))

p +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = trans_reverser('log10')) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = 'tb') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**Edit:** starting from v1.2.0 of the [`scales`](https://rdrr.io/cran/scales/man/compose_trans.html) package, this will also work

```r
library(scales)

p +
  scale_x_continuous(
    trans  = compose_trans("log10", "reverse"),
    breaks = c(100, 10, 1)
  ) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = 'tb') +
  theme_bw()

p +
  scale_x_continuous(
    trans  = compose_trans("log10", "reverse"),
    labels = label_log()
  ) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = 'tb') +
  theme_bw()
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The logticks are not correct. The ticks should be spaced further apart near each power of ten (1, 10, 100) and then get closer.

Answer (score 6):

Just thought I put updated answer to this question that does not require writing your own transformation. As of [scales](https://cran.r-project.org/package=scales) version 1.2.0 (released in April 2022), transformation composition is handled by the scales package directly. Use `scale_x_continuous()`, with the `trans` argument as a vector with both `log10` and `reverse`. You need to put `log10` before `reverse` or you'll get an error; the transformations are applied in the order specified.

```
p + scale_x_continuous(trans = c("log10", "reverse"))
```

The documentation for [`scales::compose_trans`](https://rdrr.io/cran/scales/man/compose_trans.html) even has this usage as an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the logarithm directly inside the ggplot function, in the `aes()` specification:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=runif(10))
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x = log10(x), y=y)) + geom_point()
```

and then reverse the x axis

```
p + scale_x_reverse()
```

in this way your data is not altered, but you can scale the graph

Comment: I like this answer and it works. Instead of `scale_x_reverse()` one could also write `-log10(x)` above.

Comment: Thank you! I think the solution `-log10(x)` is good, but have to be careful because you end up with the X-axis in negative values.