# Plot negative values in logarithmic scale with ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, log-analysis

I need to plot with ggplot2 package in R a graph with some negative values using an x logarithmic scale.

For example I want to plot these points using an x logarithmic scale

```
x <- c(-1,-10,-100)
y <- c(1,2,3)
```

I know that the logarithm of a negative value in R produces a NA value, but I need a result like this:

[image: click to view the picture]

Is this possible using ggplot2?

Answer (score 16):

For this, I find the `pseudolog10_trans` transformation from the `ggallin` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggallin/README.html)
to be very helpful, as it can accomodate situations with both positive and negative numbers on a log scale.  E.g.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggallin)

x <- c(-1,-10,-100, 1, 10, 100)
y <- c(1,2,3, 1,2,3)

df = data.frame(x = x, y = y)

My_Plot = ggplot(
    df, 
    aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_x_continuous(trans = pseudolog10_trans)

My_Plot
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two problems to solve - calculate log from negative values and then combine logarithmic scale and reverse scale.

To combine log and reverse scales you can use solution provided by @Briand Diggs on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053899/how-to-get-a-reversed-log10-scale-in-ggplot2).

```
library(scales)
reverselog_trans <- function(base = exp(1)) {
    trans <- function(x) -log(x, base)
    inv <- function(x) base^(-x)
    trans_new(paste0("reverselog-", format(base)), trans, inv, 
              log_breaks(base = base), 
              domain = c(1e-100, Inf))
}
```

To make it work with negative values, provide `x` values as `-x` in `ggplot()` call and then use another transformation for `labels=` inside `scale_x_continuous()` to get back negative values.

```
df<-data.frame(x=c(-1,-10,-100),y= c(1,2,3))
ggplot(df,aes(-x,y))+geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(trans=reverselog_trans(base=10),
                     labels=trans_format("identity", function(x) -x))
```

[image]

Comment: Another question..what I have to do if I also have positive data in x axis? For exemple 'x <- c(-10,1,10)'...

Comment: How, then, do you explain the possibility of log-scaling axes in Motion Charts, even with negative values?